# csv writer not closing file

Tags: python, csv

im reading a csv file and then writing a new one:

```
import csv

with open('thefile.csv', 'rb') as f:
  data = list(csv.reader(f))

import collections
counter = collections.defaultdict(int)
for row in data:
    counter[row[11]] += 1

writer = csv.writer(open('/pythonwork/thefile_subset1.csv', 'w'))
for row in data:
    if counter[row[11]] >= 500:
       writer.writerow(row)
```

for some reason i cannot get the csv.writer to close the file. when i open the file it opens it as READ ONLY because it says that is still open.

how do i close thefile_subset1.csv after i am done with it?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

```
with open('/pythonwork/thefile_subset1.csv', 'w') as outfile:
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)
    for row in data:
        if counter[row[11]] >= 500:
           writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: Didn't work for me while continuously writing to a CSV file until a `KeyboardInterrupt` occurs. `flush()` method solved the problem. Checkout the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76193980/10400598) I provided.

Answer (score 25):

You can break out the open command into its own variable, so that you can close it later.

```
f = open('/pythonwork/thefile_subset1.csv', 'w')
writer = csv.writer(f)
f.close()
```

`csv.writer` throws a `ValueError` if you try to write to a closed file.

Comment: It would be better to use another `with` statement, as was used to read the data in to begin with.

Comment: Agreed. I have to get into the habit of using `with` myself.

Answer (score 6):

close the file, not the csv writer. To do this, you'll need to open the file first before instantiating your writer rather than keeping it all in one line.

```
import csv
import collections

with open('thefile.csv', 'rb') as f:
    data = list(csv.reader(f))

counter = collections.defaultdict(int)
for row in data:
    counter[row[11]] += 1

f.close()  # good idea to close if you're done with it

fSubset = open('/pythonwork/thefile_subset1.csv', 'w')
writer = csv.writer(fSubset)
for row in data:
    if counter[row[11]] >= 500:
        writer.writerow(row)

fSubset.close()
```

Also, I would suggest keeping your imports at the top of the script and closing the first file when you're done with it.

Comment: `f.close()` is unnecessary. Why not use `with open` for `fSubset`?

Comment: I'm working with a class that uses (does not extend!) a csv writer, with the writer being shared across several methods indefinitely.  The "with open as" pattern doesn't fit all use cases. Ensuring that there is a way to clean up the open file descriptor is important for a long running process.

Answer (score 5):

Force the writer to clean up:

```
del writer
```

Comment: -1 There's no guarantee that the cleanup action will happen immediately (it depends on which implementation of Python you're using).

Comment: The [`del` statement](http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-del_stmt) *only* removes the name binding: "Deletion of a name removes the binding of that name from the local or global namespace, depending on whether the name occurs in a global statement in the same code block." It doesn't say anything about when cleanup might happen.

Comment: @James Roth, while this probably will work for CPython, it is a really bad idea. It won't work for Jython for example as `writer` will not be closed until it is gc'd. Python says nothing about when the file would be closed by deleting the reference to `writer`. More importantly though it's disguising the intent, which is to close the file which harms readability

Comment: oy vey james this is really a horrific idea indeed, horrificable

Comment: you might be able to redeem yourself: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3348460/python-getting-rid-of-extra-line

Comment: Haha, okay, okay, I was wrong. This was a lame attempt to push my score over 1000!

Comment: +1 Only answer that fixes my problem.  All the others are retroactive (i.e. here's what you should do in the future).  Should be noted that you should call `gc.collect()` immediately afterward for manually starting garbage collection.

Answer (score 0):

Although it might deteriorate the performance of your application, `flush()` is also a solution to this problem.

```
with open("path/to/file.csv", "w", newline="") as csvFile:
    # ... do your things ...
    # ... write to the CSV file ...
       
    csvFile.flush()
```

You can either call it at the end of your writing loop or after each call to the `writerow(..)` method of your writer. In my case, where I continuously write into a CSV file unless the program is terminated, this was the only working solution.

By the way, if you wonder what causes this situation, you better take a look at the file caching methodology of your operating system. This is actually caused by a buffering mechanism implemented to enhance the file I/O performance of our computers.

Answer (score -2):

Look at the difference:

```
with open('thefile.csv', 'rb') as f:
    data = list(csv.reader(f))
```

vs:

```
writer = csv.writer(open('/pythonwork/thefile_subset1.csv', 'w'))
```

Comment: so what is the answer>? this is confusing