# How to create a text file in python without csv.writer?

Tags: python, csv, text-files

I need a comma seperated txt file with txt extension. 
"a,b,c"

I used csv.writer to create a csv file changed the extension. Another prog would not  use/process the data. I tried "wb", "w."

```
F = open(Fn, 'w')
w = csv.writer(F)
w.writerow(sym)
F.close()
```

opened with notepad ---These are the complete files.
Their file: created using their gui used three symbols

```
PDCO,ICUI,DVA
```

my file : created using python

```
PDCO,ICUI,DVA
```

Tested: open thier file- worked, opened my file - failed. 
Simple open and close with save in notepad. open my file-- worked

```
Works= 'PDCO,ICUI,DVA' 
Fails= 'PDCO,ICUI,DVA\r\r\n'
```

Edit: writing txt file without Cvs writer.....

```
sym = ['MHS','MRK','AIG']

with open(r'C:\filename.txt', 'w') as F:    # also try 'w'
    for s in sym[:-1]:                      # separate all but the last
        F.write(s + ',')                    # symbols with commas
        F.write(sym[-1])                    # end with the last symbol
```

Comment: So what exactly is your problem?  I don't quite get it yet, please try to be more specific.

Comment: And what's the problem you're facing? .csv are .txt files, too (just different extension).

Comment: Prob, dont know...... I used the created file as source file instead of typing in the info. the other prog just ignored it.

Comment: "just ignored it"?  What can this possibly mean?

Comment: @lott. A gui allows me to enter in sample info or enter info then save as txt file. So, I save as text file. test using their txt file it works. Now, create my own txt file with python. The gui import of info just ignores my txt file. I dont know their "dialect" or method for saving txt files. But, would prefer not inputting a list, when I could create it with python and use it instead

Comment: @user428862.  "ignores"?  Didn't upload?  Didn't process?  Didn't provide an error messages?  Crashed your browser?  Crashed your PC?  Crashed the server?  "ignores" isn't a useful word.

Comment: @lott "Didn't upload? Didn't process?"   I took python created file. Opened it in notepad, saved it. The third party gui read it.

Comment: @user428862: Please post the full name (with extension) of "their txt file", and the first three lines of the file, and the full name (with extension) of "your txt file", and the first three lines of the file.

Comment: The file name isnt the issue both are ????.txt. the first three lines: how? thanks for help.

Comment: @user428862: "the first three lines:"?  You open the files.  Both of them.  You copy the first three lines of each file.  You **update** the question with the first three lines of each file.  When you're done, you'll have "post ... first three lines of the file" as requested.

Comment: @user428862: load the file in Notepad, select and copy the first three lines. Edit your question, at the bottom add 'their file: ' + paste and format as code (curly brackets in button bar at top of editor form). Repeat for your file.

Comment: @user428862: "the first three lines".   Not the first line.  The first 3 (three) lines.

Comment: thats all there is....those are the completed files...

Comment: It's not clear to me that opening the files in notepad and pasting the contents is going to help. Obviously the difference between the files isn't showing up in notepad or the OP wouldn't need our help; probably notepad is silently changing the file in some way. My suggestion would be to open the files in a hex editor; but I don't know a windows hex editor.

Comment: it would be easier to programmatically 1) write file with python, 2)open and save with notepad to same location.

Comment: @senderle: Notepad++ has a hex editor plugin. HxD is a good standalone hex editor. Just for future reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
with open('file_that_works.csv', 'rb') as testfile:     # file is automatically
    d = csv.Sniffer().sniff(testfile.read(1024))        # closed at end of with
                                                        # block
with open(Fn, 'wb') as F:       # also try 'w'
    w = csv.writer(F, dialect=d)
    w.writerow(sym)
```

To explain further: this looks at a sample of a working .csv file and deduces its format. Then it uses that format to write a new .csv file that, hopefully, will not have to be resaved in notepad.

---

Edit: if the program you're using doesn't accept multi-line input (?!) then don't use csv. Just do something like this:

```
syms = ['JAGHS','GJKDGJ','GJDFAJ']
with open('filename.txt', 'wb') as F:       
    for s in syms[:-1]:                     # separate all but the last
        F.write(s + ',')                    # symbols with commas
    F.write(syms[-1])                       # end with the last symbol
```

Or more tersely:

```
with open('filename.txt', 'wb') as F:
    F.write(','.join(syms))
```

Also, check different file extensions (i.e. .txt, .csv, etc) to make sure that's not the problem. If this program chokes on a newline, then anything is possible.

Comment: :-(. still didnt work. Then I took the txt created by third party, use it as "Sniffer" file. ran it in above code. still didnt work...... "b" does not work. damn it... at complete loss.

Comment: Ok, well we're working through possibilities. Next thought: I notice that `Works= 'PDCO,ICUI,DVA'` doesn't have a line terminator at all. What happens when the working file has more than one line? Create a working 2-line file, and show the output of `goodf = open('file_that_works.txt', 'rb'); print repr(goodf.read(100))`

Comment: thought.... since Works= 'PDCO,ICUI,DVA' does not have line terminator, How can create a txt file without one. The third party  Works= 'PDCO,ICUI,DVA' file also may not have or need a second line. My reasoning is that the third party gui, 1) asks or symbols, 2) then click a save botton to create txt file. there is no second line. Nothings says to me that the third party file is well formed. thanks for ur help.

Comment: Are you saying that the third party app can't generate a second line? What is this program?? Perhaps it can't handle multi-line input. That would be super bizarre; and frankly in that case I can't imagine why you'd bother to use csv.writer at all. Just spew a bunch of symbols separated by commas. See above.

Comment: thanks for edit. The edit actually worked! but giving me strange symbols combining some....???? see my edit above Syms giving me MHS,AIGMRK, AIG for MHS, AIGMRK,AIG.

Comment: Python uses indentation to denote blocks. In my code, the for loop iterates over `write(s + ',')` multiple times, but the final line, `write(syms[-1])` is only executed once. But when you copied my code, you didn't preserve the indentation. Somehow the last line got indented another level, and so the for loop iterates over both lines, so each time it writes, it appends the last item in the list -- AIG. Make sense?

Comment: Better to just use the 2-line `','.join()` version anyway.

Answer (score 3):

To me, it look like you don't exactly know you third party application input format. If a .CSV isn't reconized, it might be something else.

Did you try to change the delimiter fromn ';' to ','

```
import csv
spamWriter = csv.writer(open('eggs.csv', 'wb'), delimiter=',', quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
spamWriter.writerow(['Spam'] * 5 + ['Baked Beans'])
spamWriter.writerow(['Spam', 'Lovely Spam', 'Wonderful Spam'])
```

Take a look in the [CSV Python API](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html)

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is your file write mode, as per [CSV file written with Python has blank lines between each row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3348460/python-getting-rid-of-extra-line)

If you create your csv file like

```
csv.writer(open('myfile.csv', 'w'))
```

csv.writer ends its lines in '\r\n', and Python's text file handling (on Windows machines) then converts '\n' to '\r\n', resulting in lines ending in '\r\r\n'. Many programs will choke on this; Notepad recognizes it as a problem and strips the extra '\r' out.

If you use

```
csv.writer(open('myfile.csv', 'wb'))
```

it produces the expected '\r\n' line ending, which should work as desired.

**Edit:** @senderle has a good point; try the following:

```
goodf = open('file_that_works.txt', 'rb')
print repr(goodf.read(100))
badf =  open('file_that_fails.txt', 'rb')
print repr(badf.read(100))
```

paste the results of that here, so we can see how the two compare byte-for-byte.

Comment: I took python created file. Opened it in notepad, saved it. The third party gui read it.

Comment: @user428862: DETAILS, already! File name? File extension? Changing the file extension fixed the problem? If you create the file with the proper extension in the first place, do you still need to resave it with Notepad?

Comment: Sorry.. No, same filename. same extension. just opened the file and closed, nothing else.  The file name and extension is not the issue. my guess something how notepad saved vs python created ...something

Comment: Ok! Now we're getting somewhere; so it is probably the file's text encoding. Are you using any odd character sets, unicode etc? Do you get any sort of error message loading the pre-Notepad file?

Comment: There is nothing odd about text. Stock symbols no numbers. I get no error messages. the fail is a silent fail.

Comment: @ new idea, the first attempt was with 'wb', then 'w'. both had the same result.

Comment: Works= 'PDCO,ICUI,DVA'
Fails= 'PDCO,ICUI,DVA\r\r\n'
Now the file was created with "w" not 'wb', Opening/Save files with 'wb' creation fails......

Comment: \r\r\n says that open(filename, 'w') is the problem, and open(filename, 'wb') ought to solve it. "fails" does not help; WHAT fails? Fails HOW? How do you know it failed? What did it do which it shouldn't, or not do that it should? Were there any error messages?

Comment: @Hugh Bothwell, good call, I didn't think of using python itself, silly of me! In any case, we now know that the \r\r\n is probably the problem. Could the problem be the "dialect=excel" keyword?

Comment: I keep saying their is no error msg. When it works, the data is accepted. When it fails, data is not accepted. Try again, data is not accepted. I call it a fail. it does not say fail, I call it a fail.

Comment: @senderle. I dont use "dialect=excel." But, I recall the default is to "dialect=excel." maybe something here.

Comment: @user428862: have you tried the `Sniffer` class? It looks at a sample and deduces the dialect for you. See here: http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html#csv.Dialect

Comment: Ran code below, it gave me nothing back....really starting to get annoyed      import csv

csvfile = open('C:\Fails.txt', "rb")
dialect = csv.Sniffer().sniff(csvfile.read(100))
csvfile.seek(0)
reader = csv.reader(csvfile, dialect)

Comment: You're opening the "fails" file. You need to open the "works" file -- the point is that Sniffer reads the file that works and figures out the format it uses. I would guess that you want to read more than 100 bytes as well -- it's safe even if the file is shorter than that. See my answer below.

Comment: below gave mesame blank output  could be user error. csvfile = open('C:\works.txt', "rb")
dialect = csv.Sniffer().sniff(csvfile.read(1024))
csvfile.seek(0)
reader = csv.reader(csvfile, dialect)

Comment: see my answer for code -- you're still not doing what I mean you to do. The `csvfile.seek(0)` and `reader` bit from the documentation example is useless to you. The point is to get the format by Sniffing, and then use that format to __write__, not to read.

Answer (score 1):

1. So, I save as text file.
2. Now, create my own txt file with python.

What are the **exact** differences between their file and your file?  Exact.

Comment: @user428862: What?  What are the **exact** differences between the files?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that @Hugh's comment is correct that it's an encoding issue.

When you do a Save As in notepad, what's selected in the Encoding dropdown?  If you select different encodings do some or all of those fail to be opened by the 3rd party program?

Comment: If you select a different encoding to save as in Notepad does it stop working?  If so your 3rd party program doesn't know how to properly handle the encoding that the CSV writer is setting (most likely either UTF8 or some other form of unicode).  If no non-ANSI characters are used then text will look identical to a program that understands the encodings, but even though the text is the same that doesn't mean the file is the same.

Comment: Read http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html to at least have a basic understanding of what character encoding means.  Text isn't just text.  Most modern day programs should ideally understand unicode but some don't take the time to support it properly, and it seems like your 3rd party app is one of them.  There may be a setting for the CSV exporter to export in ANSI/ASCII which should solve your problem, but really it's the 3rd party program, that's broken by modern standards.