# Python: How to have a user input add a column in a csv file?

Tags: python, csv, directory, user-input

I'm creating a code that creates CSVs then puts it in a folder. I want a user to be able to modify the csv file by adding in another column and inserting values in the columns then saves it back into the folder. I hope this makes sense. Here is a part of my code.

This is how I wrote the directory of the path = r"C:\Users\Documents\workersInfo*.csv"

```
driver.writerow(["cities", "name", "milesDriven"])
driver.writerow(["Greensborrow", "Peter", "6"])
driver.writerow(["Winsdow", "Tony", "7"])
driver.writerow(["Marlboro", "Esther", "8"])
```

Comment: can you put the basic code you have written for this?

Comment: see this post hope it will help  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12648717/how-can-i-place-user-input-into-a-csv-file

Comment: What are you having trouble with?  This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.  Invest some time with [the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) practicing the examples. It will give you an idea of the tools Python offers to help you solve your problem.