# How to save stock data to csv file using python

Tags: python, api, stock

I am trying to save the stock data I downloaded from a API using python. But I have no idea about how to do this.

The data is printed out as below:

```
>>> 
{'20140311': {'1030': {'total_price': 9421626, 'end': 6.76, 'high': 6.85, 'start': 6.78, 'low': 6.67, 'volumn': 1396431}, '1130': {'total_price': 5042807, 'end': 6.86, 'high': 6.91, 'start': 6.76, 'low': 6.76, 'volumn': 735220}, '1400': {'total_price': 5410292, 'end': 6.79, 'high': 6.9, 'start': 6.88, 'low': 6.76, 'volumn': 792890}, '1500': {'total_price': 6470290, 'end': 6.83, 'high': 6.85, 'start': 6.79, 'low': 6.74, 'volumn': 954111}},....
```

My last several lines of the code is:

```
def main():
    g = getStock60MIN('000030', 'sz')
    print g

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Borrowing from [How do I write a Python dictionary to a csv file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10373247/how-do-i-write-a-python-dictionary-to-a-csv-file)

You have a nested dict structure. Maybe the following will help:

```
import csv

my_dict = {
  '20140311': {
    '1030': {
      'total_price': 9421626, 'end': 6.76, 'high': 6.85, 'start': 6.78, 'low': 6.67, 'volumn': 1396431
    },
    '1130': {
      'total_price': 5042807, 'end': 6.86, 'high': 6.91, 'start': 6.76, 'low': 6.76, 'volumn': 735220
    },
    '1400': {
      'total_price': 5410292, 'end': 6.79, 'high': 6.9, 'start': 6.88, 'low': 6.76, 'volumn': 792890
    }, 
    '1500': {
      'total_price': 6470290, 'end': 6.83, 'high': 6.85, 'start': 6.79, 'low': 6.74, 'volumn': 954111
    }
  }
}

def initialize_keys():
  for dict1 in my_dict.itervalues():
    for dict2 in dict1.itervalues():
      return dict2.keys()

with open('mycsvfile.csv', 'wb') as f:
  w = csv.DictWriter(f, initialize_keys())
  w.writeheader()
  for dict1 in my_dict.itervalues():
    for dict2 in dict1.itervalues():
      w.writerow(dict2)
```

I don't know what do you want to do with your secondary dictionary keys, though (the `1030`, `1130`, `1400` and `1500`) My method disregards them.

These are the contents of `mycsvfile.csv`:

```
total_price,end,high,start,low,volumn
9421626,6.76,6.85,6.78,6.67,1396431
5042807,6.86,6.91,6.76,6.76,735220
5410292,6.79,6.9,6.88,6.76,792890
6470290,6.83,6.85,6.79,6.74,954111
```

Take a look to the [csv](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module in Python. It'll probably give you more ideas.

---

**UPDATE AS PER OP'S COMMENT:**

Since the keys of the first dictionary are dates and the keys of the second dictionary are times, a `datetime.datetime` instance can be instanciated and then written in the csv file:

```
import csv
import datetime

my_dict = {
  '20140311': {
    '1030': {
      'total_price': 9421626, 'end': 6.76, 'high': 6.85, 'start': 6.78, 'low': 6.67, 'volumn': 1396431
    },
    '1130': {
      'total_price': 5042807, 'end': 6.86, 'high': 6.91, 'start': 6.76, 'low': 6.76, 'volumn': 735220
    },
    '1400': {
      'total_price': 5410292, 'end': 6.79, 'high': 6.9, 'start': 6.88, 'low': 6.76, 'volumn': 792890
    }, 
    '1500': {
      'total_price': 6470290, 'end': 6.83, 'high': 6.85, 'start': 6.79, 'low': 6.74, 'volumn': 954111
    }
  }
}

def initialize_keys():
  for dict1 in my_dict.itervalues():
    for dict2 in dict1.itervalues():
      return dict2.keys()

with open('mycsvfile.csv', 'wb') as f:
  w = csv.DictWriter(f, ['datetime'] + initialize_keys())
  w.writeheader()
  for datestr, dict1 in my_dict.iteritems():
    for timestr, dict2 in dict1.iteritems():
      whole_row = {}
      whole_row['datetime'] = datetime.datetime\
                .strptime(datestr + timestr, '%Y%m%d%H%M')\
                .strftime('%Y/%m/%d %H:%M')
      whole_row.update(dict2)
      w.writerow(whole_row)
```

This produces the following output:

```
datetime,total_price,end,high,start,low,volumn
2014/03/11 10:30,9421626,6.76,6.85,6.78,6.67,1396431
2014/03/11 11:30,5042807,6.86,6.91,6.76,6.76,735220
2014/03/11 14:00,5410292,6.79,6.9,6.88,6.76,792890
2014/03/11 15:00,6470290,6.83,6.85,6.79,6.74,954111
```

Comment: 1030, 1130, 1400 and 1500 represents 10:00,11:30,14:00 and 15:00. These are the specific time point. Can you add them followed by the date? Thanks!

Comment: That diverts from the initial question and may be confusing for other people who find your question, but there it is.