# How to save Multi-layered dictionary to csv

Tags: python, csv

I have a three layed dictionary that I need to save it in csv format. I followed the code in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10373247/how-do-i-write-a-python-dictionary-to-a-csv-file). but i get only two rows with all the data dumped in one row.

How can I separate data and write them into separate cells.

```
{'Alpha': {'2010': {'216': 0.0, '217': 0.0, '218': 195.37308756510416}}}
```

There are other keys (`Beta` and `Omega`) at the same level as `Alpha`.

I'd like the final product to look like:

```
Alpha,2010,216,0.0
Alpha,2010,217,0.0
Alpha,2010,218,195.37308756510416
.....
Beta, .....
```

and preferably save it in a `.csv` file, but text file will do too.

This code is what I have tried.

```
with open('mycsvfile.csv', 'wb') as f: 
    w = csv.DictWriter(f, datadictionary.keys())
    w.writeheader()
    w.writerow(datadictionary)
```

Thanks

Comment: provide a sample output you looking for and what have you done

Comment: Perhaps you could tell us what each part of the dictionary is supposed to be and what the csv should look like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, a suggestion: if you're going to post some data that you're processing, omit all but a small representative sample - ain't nobody got time to ready through all those numbers scrolling off the edge of the screen.

Here's a smaller sample of your input:

```
{'Alpha': {'2010': {'216': 0.0,  '217': 0.0, '218': 195.4 } } }
```

One of the things you don't state is whether there could be other keys at the same level as 'Alpha' and again at the level of '2010'. If so, then your csv is going to have to include those values in each row also.

Here's a suggested csv format, with column headers:

```
section,year,key,value
Alpha,2010,216,0.0
Alpha,2010,217,0.0
Alpha,2010,218,195.37308756510416
... etc.
```

So how do you create this?

Just iterate through your dictionaries, and keep track of the outer dictionary keys to insert in each row:

```
text = "section,year,key,value\n"
for sectionName in myData:
    yearData = myData[sectionName]
    for year in yearData:
        keyValueDict = yearData[year]
        for key in keyValueDict:
            value = keyValueDict[key]
            text += sectionName + "," + year + "," + key + "," + str(value) + "\n"
```

To write the csv file:

```
f = open("mydata.csv", "w")
f.write(text)
f.close()
```

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I tried to elaborate more in the original post. So I'm assuming I can dump the `test` into a `csv` file?

Comment: Yes just open a file and call write() with text as the content and it will be a csv file.

Answer (score 0):

If your output is supposed to look like this:

```
    ['Alpha', '2010', '217', 0.0]
    ['Alpha', '2010', '215', 0.0]
    ['Alpha', '2010', '205', 0.0]
    ['Alpha', '2010', '213', 0.0]
```

this code will do it (where dd is your dictionary):

```
    def do_keys(d, plst, lvl=0):
        for elem in d:
            plst[lvl] = elem
            if isinstance(d[elem], dict):
                do_keys(d[elem], plst, lvl+1)
            else:
                plst[-1] = d[elem]
                print plst

    do_keys(dd, ['']*4)
```

just replace the print pls with a write to your csv file

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't directly answer the question, but if possible, you should think of another format that can handle nested dictionaries naturally. Python has a JSON module, and it is quite simple to use. With `A` as your nested dictionary:

```
import json
print json.dumps(A, indent=True)
```

This gives (truncated):

```
{
 "Alpha": {
  "2010": {
   "216": 0.0, 
   "217": 0.0, 
   "215": 0.0, 
   ....
   "111": 0.0, 
   "169": 0.0
  }
 }
}
```

The advantage here is two-fold. JSON files are widely portable, and if need be the file is still human-readable. Saving it to a file is also easy:

```
with open("myfile.json",'w') as FOUT:
    js = json.dumps(A, indent=True)
    FOUT.write(js)
```