# The output values in one line.(python3/csv.write)

Tags: python-3.x, csv

I write a list of dics into a csv file. But the output is in one line. How could witer each value in new lines?

```
    f = open(os.getcwd() + '/friend1.csv','w+',newline='')
    for Member in MemberList:
        f.write(str(Member))
    f.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the [writing example](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#examples) in the csv module of the standard library and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10373247/how-do-i-write-a-python-dictionary-to-a-csv-file). Either that, or simply append a newline ("\n") after each write: `f.write(str(Member)) + "\n")`.