# Getting dictionary keys and values into dataset

Tags: dictionary, dataset, python-2.5

I'm wondering if there is a easy way to parse the dictionary data into a dataset, because on my case I am trying to directly convert my dictionary data into dataset or getting all the keys or values inside my dictionary. Or is there a library or function that can directly convert/export my dictionary data into csv or xls.

Here is my sample data:

```
dict = {'Result': {'Path': '\\\\10.81.67.162\\DLCx Logs\\DLCx04\\2016\\2016_12\\2016-12-05\\LLA_RunNo_001_0052\\2016-12-05_001_A3D.txt', 'Data': {'PM3 (DLCXIC)_1': {'Steps': {'10': {'ProcStat': {'Etch PBN Filament (A)': {'Median': '0.107'}, 'Etch Source Magnet (A)': {'Median': '0.000'}, 'Etch Forward RF Power (W)': {'Median': '0.000'}, 'DC Current Power (W)': {'Median': '500.000'}, 'Etch Beam Current (mA)': {'Median': '2.747'}, 'Etch Suppressor Current (mA)': {'Median': '0.000'}, 'DC Current Impedance': {'Median': '255.000'}, 'Etch PBN Body (A)': {'Median': '0.000'}, 'Etch Beam Voltage (V)': {'Median': '2.106'}, 'Etch PBN Gas Actual Flow (SCCM)': {'Median': '0.000'}, 'Etch Reflected RF Power (W)': {'Median': '0.000'}, 'DC Current Current  (mA)': {'Median': '1.400'}, 'Depo Gas 1 Actual Flow (SCCM)': {'Median': '36.993'}, 'Depo Gas 2 Actual Flow (SCCM)': {'Median': '0.000'}, 'Chamber Pressure': {'Median': '4.3e-004'}, 'Etch Suppressor Voltage (V)': {'Median': '8.789'}, 'DC Current Voltage (V)': {'Median': '357.000'}, 'Etch Gas 1 Actual Flow (SCCM)': {'Median': '0.000'}, 'Etch Gas 3 Actual Flow (SCCM)': {'Median': '0.053'}, 'Etch Gas 2 Actual Flow (SCCM)': {'Median': '0.000'}}, 'stepname': None, 'runtime': None, 'steptime': None, 'tiltangle': None, 'stepsendby': None, 'champress': None}, '11': {'ProcStat': {'Etch PBN Filament (A)': {'Median': '0.102'}, 'Etch Source Magnet (A)': {'Median': '0.000'}, 'Etch Forward RF Power (W)': {'Median': '0.000'}, 'DC Current Power (W)': {'Median': '500.000'}, 'Etch Beam Current (mA)': {'Median': '2.686'}, 'Etch Suppressor Current (mA)': {'Median': '0.000'}, 'DC Current Impedance': {'Median': '391.150'}, 'Etch PBN Body (A)': {'Median': '0.000'}, 'Etch Beam Voltage (V)': {'Median': '7.599'}, 'Etch PBN Gas Actual Flow (SCCM)': {'Median': '0.000'}, 'Etch Reflected RF Power (W)': {'Median': '0.000'}, 'DC Current Current  (mA)': {'Median': '1.130'}, 'Depo Gas 1 Actual Flow (SCCM)': {'Median': '26.993'}, 'Depo Gas 2 Actual Flow (SCCM)': {'Median': '12.996'}, 'Chamber Pressure': {'Median': '4.2e-004'}, 'Etch Suppressor Voltage (V)': {'Median': '13.977'}, 'DC Current Voltage (V)': {'Median': '442.000'}, 'Etch Gas 1 Actual Flow (SCCM)': {'Median': '0.000'}, 'Etch Gas 3 Actual Flow (SCCM)': {'Median': '0.053'}, 'Etch Gas 2 Actual Flow (SCCM)': {'Median': '0.000'}}, 'stepname': None, 'runtime': None, 'steptime': None, 'tiltangle': None, 'stepsendby': None, 'champress': None}, '12': {'ProcStat': {'Etch PBN Filament (A)': {'Median': '0.103'}, 'Etch Source Magnet (A)': {'Median': '0.000'}, 'Etch Forward RF Power (W)': {'Median': '0.000'}, 'DC Current Power (W)': {'Median': '0.000'}, 'Etch Beam Current (mA)': {'Median': '2.777'}, 'Etch Suppressor Current (mA)': {'Median': '0.000'}, 'DC Current Impedance': {'Median': '0.000'}, 'Etch PBN Body (A)': {'Median': '0.000'}, 'Etch Beam Voltage (V)': {'Median': '2.014'}, 'Etch PBN Gas Actual Flow (SCCM)': {'Median': '0.000'}, 'Etch Reflected RF Power (W)': {'Median': '0.000'}, 'DC Current Current  (mA)': {'Median': '0.000'}, 'Depo Gas 1 Actual Flow (SCCM)': {'Median': '0.000'}, 'Depo Gas 2 Actual Flow (SCCM)': {'Median': '0.000'}, 'Chamber Pressure': {'Median': '1.4e-006'}, 'Etch Suppressor Voltage (V)': {'Median': '3.662'}, 'DC Current Voltage (V)': {'Median': '0.000'}, 'Etch Gas 1 Actual Flow (SCCM)': {'Median': '0.000'}, 'Etch Gas 3 Actual Flow (SCCM)': {'Median': '0.053'}, 'Etch Gas 2 Actual Flow (SCCM)': {'Median': '0.000'}}, 'stepname': None, 'runtime': None, 'steptime': None, 'tiltangle': None, 'stepsendby': None, 'champress': None}, '13': {'ProcStat': {'Etch PBN Filament (A)': {'Median': '57.108'}, 'Etch Source Magnet (A)': {'Median': '0.510'}, 'Etch Forward RF Power (W)': {'Median': '356.000'}, 'DC Current Power (W)': {'Median': '0.000'}, 'Etch Beam Current (mA)': {'Median': '120.605'}, 'Etch Suppressor Current (mA)': {'Median': '4.688'}, 'DC Current Impedance': {'Median': '0.000'}, 'Etch PBN Body (A)': {'Median': '0.600'}, 'Etch Beam Voltage (V)': {'Median': '200.089'}, 'Etch PBN Gas Actual Flow (SCCM)': {'Median': '6.999'}, 'Etch Reflected RF Power (W)': {'Median': '0.000'}, 'DC Current Current  (mA)': {'Median': '0.000'}, 'Depo Gas 1 Actual Flow (SCCM)': {'Median': '0.000'}, 'Depo Gas 2 Actual Flow (SCCM)': {'Median': '0.000'}, 'Chamber Pressure': {'Median': '2.7e-004'}, 'Etch Suppressor Voltage (V)': {'Median': '600.250'}, 'DC Current Voltage (V)': {'Median': '0.000'}, 'Etch Gas 1 Actual Flow (SCCM)': {'Median': '15.995'}, 'Etch Gas 3 Actual Flow (SCCM)': {'Median': '0.053'}, 'Etch Gas 2 Actual Flow (SCCM)': {'Median': '0.000'}}, 'stepname': None, 'runtime': None, 'steptime': None, 'tiltangle': None, 'stepsendby': None, 'champress': None}, '14': {'ProcStat': {'Etch PBN Filament (A)': {'Median': '0.107'}, 'Etch Source Magnet (A)': {'Median': '0.001'}, 'Etch Forward RF Power (W)': {'Median': '0.000'}, 'DC Current Power (W)': {'Median': '0.000'}, 'Etch Beam Current (mA)': {'Median': '2.869'}, 'Etch Suppressor Current (mA)': {'Median': '0.000'}, 'DC Current Impedance': {'Median': '0.000'}, 'Etch PBN Body (A)': {'Median': '0.000'}, 'Etch Beam Voltage (V)': {'Median': '1.831'}, 'Etch PBN Gas Actual Flow (SCCM)': {'Median': '0.000'}, 'Etch Reflected RF Power (W)': {'Median': '0.000'}, 'DC Current Current  (mA)': {'Median': '0.000'}, 'Depo Gas 1 Actual Flow (SCCM)': {'Median': '0.000'}, 'Depo Gas 2 Actual Flow (SCCM)': {'Median': '0.000'}, 'Chamber Pressure': {'Median': '2.5e-005'}, 'Etch Suppressor Voltage (V)': {'Median': '3.906'}, 'DC Current Voltage (V)': {'Median': '0.000'}, 'Etch Gas 1 Actual Flow (SCCM)': {'Median': '0.000'}, 'Etch Gas 3 Actual Flow (SCCM)': {'Median': '0.053'}, 'Etch Gas 2 Actual Flow (SCCM)': {'Median': '0.000'}}, 'stepname': None, 'runtime': None, 'steptime': None, 'tiltangle': None, 'stepsendby': None, 'champress': None}, '15': {'ProcStat': {'Etch PBN Filament (A)': {'Median': '0.104'}, 'Etch Source Magnet (A)': {'Median': '0.000'}, 'Etch Forward RF Power (W)': {'Median': '0.000'}, 'DC Current Power (W)': {'Median': '500.000'}, 'Etch Beam Current (mA)': {'Median': '2.686'}, 'Etch Suppressor Current (mA)': {'Median': '0.000'}, 'DC Current Impedance': {'Median': '255.000'}, 'Etch PBN Body (A)': {'Median': '0.000'}, 'Etch Beam Voltage (V)': {'Median': '1.831'}, 'Etch PBN Gas Actual Flow (SCCM)': {'Median': '0.000'}, 'Etch Reflected RF Power (W)': {'Median': '0.000'}, 'DC Current Current  (mA)': {'Median': '1.400'}, 'Depo Gas 1 Actual Flow (SCCM)': {'Median': '36.993'}, 'Depo Gas 2 Actual Flow (SCCM)': {'Median': '0.000'}, 'Chamber Pressure': {'Median': '4.3e-004'}, 'Etch Suppressor Voltage (V)': {'Median': '8.606'}, 'DC Current Voltage (V)': {'Median': '357.000'}, 'Etch Gas 1 Actual Flow (SCCM)': {'Median': '0.000'}, 'Etch Gas 3 Actual Flow (SCCM)': {'Median': '0.053'}, 'Etch Gas 2 Actual Flow (SCCM)': {'Median': '0.000'}}, 'stepname': None, 'runtime': None, 'steptime': None, 'tiltangle': None, 'stepsendby': None, 'champress': None}, '16': {'ProcStat': {'Etch PBN Filament (A)': {'Median': '0.104'}, 'Etch Source Magnet (A)': {'Median': '0.000'}, 'Etch Forward RF Power (W)': {'Median': '0.000'}, 'DC Current Power (W)': {'Median': '500.000'}, 'Etch Beam Current (mA)': {'Median': '2.686'}, 'Etch Suppressor Current (mA)': {'Median': '0.000'}, 'DC Current Impedance': {'Median': '391.150'}, 'Etch PBN Body (A)': {'Median': '0.000'}, 'Etch Beam Voltage (V)': {'Median': '7.690'}, 'Etch PBN Gas Actual Flow (SCCM)': {'Median': '0.000'}, 'Etch Reflected RF Power (W)': {'Median': '0.000'}, 'DC Current Current  (mA)': {'Median': '1.130'}, 'Depo Gas 1 Actual Flow (SCCM)': {'Median': '26.993'}, 'Depo Gas 2 Actual Flow (SCCM)': {'Median': '12.995'}, 'Chamber Pressure': {'Median': '4.2e-004'}, 'Etch Suppressor Voltage (V)': {'Median': '13.672'}, 'DC Current Voltage (V)': {'Median': '442.000'}, 'Etch Gas 1 Actual Flow (SCCM)': {'Median': '0.000'}, 'Etch Gas 3 Actual Flow (SCCM)': {'Median': '0.053'}, 'Etch Gas 2 Actual Flow (SCCM)': {'Median': '0.000'}}, 'stepname': None, 'runtime': None, 'steptime': None, 'tiltangle': None, 'stepsendby': None, 'champress': None}, '17': {'ProcStat': {'Etch PBN Filament (A)': {'Median': '0.103'}, 'Etch Source Magnet (A)': {'Median': '0.000'}, 'Etch Forward RF Power (W)': {'Median': '0.000'}, 'DC Current Power (W)': {'Median': '0.000'}, 'Etch Beam Current (mA)': {'Median': '2.502'}, 'Etch Suppressor Current (mA)': {'Median': '0.000'}, 'DC Current Impedance': {'Median': '0.000'}, 'Etch PBN Body (A)': {'Median': '0.000'}, 'Etch Beam Voltage (V)': {'Median': '2.106'}, 'Etch PBN Gas Actual Flow (SCCM)': {'Median': '0.000'}, 'Etch Reflected RF Power (W)': {'Median': '0.000'}, 'DC Current Current  (mA)': {'Median': '0.000'}, 'Depo Gas 1 Actual Flow (SCCM)': {'Median': '0.000'}, 'Depo Gas 2 Actual Flow (SCCM)': {'Median': '0.000'}, 'Chamber Pressure': {'Median': '2.6e-006'}, 'Etch Suppressor Voltage (V)': {'Median': '3.693'}, 'DC Current Voltage (V)': {'Median': '0.000'}, 'Etch Gas 1 Actual Flow (SCCM)': {'Median': '0.000'}, 'Etch Gas 3 Actual Flow (SCCM)': {'Median': '0.053'}, 'Etch Gas 2 Actual Flow (SCCM)': {'Median': '0.000'}}, 'stepname': None, 'runtime': None, 'steptime': None, 'tiltangle': None, 'stepsendby': None, 'champress': None}, '1': {'ProcStat': {'Etch PBN Filament (A)': {'Median': '0.098'}, 'Etch Source Magnet (A)': {'Median': '0.000'}, 'Etch Forward RF Power (W)': {'Median': '0.000'}, 'DC Current Power (W)': {'Median': '0.000'}, 'Etch Beam Current (mA)': {'Median': '2.563'}, 'Etch Suppressor Current (mA)': {'Median': '0.000'}, 'DC Current Impedance': {'Median': '0.000'}, 'Etch PBN Body (A)': {'Median': '0.000'}, 'Etch Beam Voltage (V)': {'Median': '1.648'}, 'Etch PBN Gas Actual Flow (SCCM)': {'Median': '0.000'}, 'Etch Reflected RF Power (W)': {'Median': '0.000'}, 'DC Current Current  (mA)': {'Median': '0.000'}, 'Depo Gas 1 Actual Flow (SCCM)': {'Median': '0.000'}, 'Depo Gas 2 Actual Flow (SCCM)': {'Median': '0.000'}, 'Chamber Pressure': {'Median': '1.7e-006'}, 'Etch Suppressor Voltage (V)': {'Median': '3.510'}, 'DC Current Voltage (V)': {'Median': '0.000'}, 'Etch Gas 1 Actual Flow (SCCM)': {'Median': '0.000'}, 'Etch Gas 3 Actual Flow (SCCM)': {'Median': '0.053'}, 'Etch Gas 2 Actual Flow (SCCM)': {'Median': '0.000'}}, 'stepname': None, 'runtime': None, 'steptime': None, 'tiltangle': None, 'stepsendby': None, 'champress': None}, '2': {'ProcStat': {'Etch PBN Filament (A)': {'Median': '53.858'}, 'Etch Source Magnet (A)': {'Median': '0.001'}, 'Etch Forward RF Power (W)': {'Median': '288.000'}, 'DC Current Power (W)': {'Median': '0.000'}, 'Etch Beam Current (mA)': {'Median': '99.792'}, 'Etch Suppressor Current (mA)': {'Median': '2.344'}, 'DC Current Impedance': {'Median': '0.000'}, 'Etch PBN Body (A)': {'Median': '0.303'}, 'Etch Beam Voltage (V)': {'Median': '299.652'}, 'Etch PBN Gas Actual Flow (SCCM)': {'Median': '6.999'}, 'Etch Reflected RF Power (W)': {'Median': '0.000'}, 'DC Current Current  (mA)': {'Median': '0.000'}, 'Depo Gas 1 Actual Flow (SCCM)': {'Median': '0.000'}, 'Depo Gas 2 Actual Flow (SCCM)': {'Median': '0.000'}, 'Chamber Pressure': {'Median': '2.3e-004'}, 'Etch Suppressor Voltage (V)': {'Median': '401.184'}, 'DC Current Voltage (V)': {'Median': '0.000'}, 'Etch Gas 1 Actual Flow (SCCM)': {'Median': '15.992'}, 'Etch Gas 3 Actual Flow (SCCM)': {'Median': '0.053'}, 'Etch Gas 2 Actual Flow (SCCM)': {'Median': '0.000'}}, 'stepname': None, 'runtime': None, 'steptime': None, 'tiltangle': None, 'stepsendby': None, 'champress': None}, '3': {'ProcStat': {'Etch PBN Filament (A)': {'Median': '56.603'}, 'Etch Source Magnet (A)': {'Median': '0.000'}, 'Etch Forward RF Power (W)': {'Median': '261.000'}, 'DC Current Power (W)': {'Median': '0.000'}, 'Etch Beam Current (mA)': {'Median': '100.342'}, 'Etch Suppressor Current (mA)': {'Median': '4.688'}, 'DC Current Impedance': {'Median': '0.000'}, 'Etch PBN Body (A)': {'Median': '0.505'}, 'Etch Beam Voltage (V)': {'Median': '299.744'}, 'Etch PBN Gas Actual Flow (SCCM)': {'Median': '6.999'}, 'Etch Reflected RF Power (W)': {'Median': '0.000'}, 'DC Current Current  (mA)': {'Median': '0.000'}, 'Depo Gas 1 Actual Flow (SCCM)': {'Median': '0.000'}, 'Depo Gas 2 Actual Flow (SCCM)': {'Median': '0.000'}, 'Chamber Pressure': {'Median': '2.3e-004'}, 'Etch Suppressor Voltage (V)': {'Median': '600.342'}, 'DC Current Voltage (V)': {'Median': '0.000'}, 'Etch Gas 1 Actual Flow (SCCM)': {'Median': '15.995'}, 'Etch Gas 3 Actual Flow (SCCM)': {'Median': '0.051'}, 'Etch Gas 2 Actual Flow (SCCM)': {'Median': '0.000'}}, 'stepname': None, 'runtime': None, 'steptime': None, 'tiltangle': None, 'stepsendby': None, 'champress': None}, '4': {'ProcStat': {'Etch PBN Filament (A)': {'Median': '54.365'}, 'Etch Source Magnet (A)': {'Median': '0.398'}, 'Etch Forward RF Power (W)': {'Median': '300.000'}, 'DC Current Power (W)': {'Median': '0.000'}, 'Etch Beam Current (mA)': {'Median': '2.808'}, 'Etch Suppressor Current (mA)': {'Median': '1.758'}, 'DC Current Impedance': {'Median': '0.000'}, 'Etch PBN Body (A)': {'Median': '0.530'}, 'Etch Beam Voltage (V)': {'Median': '8.057'}, 'Etch PBN Gas Actual Flow (SCCM)': {'Median': '9.998'}, 'Etch Reflected RF Power (W)': {'Median': '0.000'}, 'DC Current Current  (mA)': {'Median': '0.000'}, 'Depo Gas 1 Actual Flow (SCCM)': {'Median': '0.000'}, 'Depo Gas 2 Actual Flow (SCCM)': {'Median': '0.000'}, 'Chamber Pressure': {'Median': '2.7e-004'}, 'Etch Suppressor Voltage (V)': {'Median': '4.700'}, 'DC Current Voltage (V)': {'Median': '0.000'}, 'Etch Gas 1 Actual Flow (SCCM)': {'Median': '9.995'}, 'Etch Gas 3 Actual Flow (SCCM)': {'Median': '0.051'}, 'Etch Gas 2 Actual Flow (SCCM)': {'Median': '9.998'}}, 'stepname': None, 'runtime': None, 'steptime': None, 'tiltangle': None, 'stepsendby': None, 'champress': None}, '5': {'ProcStat': {'Etch PBN Filament (A)': {'Median': '53.937'}, 'Etch Source Magnet (A)': {'Median': '0.398'}, 'Etch Forward RF Power (W)': {'Median': '347.000'}, 'DC Current Power (W)': {'Median': '0.000'}, 'Etch Beam Current (mA)': {'Median': '99.426'}, 'Etch Suppressor Current (mA)': {'Median': '2.344'}, 'DC Current Impedance': {'Median': '0.000'}, 'Etch PBN Body (A)': {'Median': '0.495'}, 'Etch Beam Voltage (V)': {'Median': '299.652'}, 'Etch PBN Gas Actual Flow (SCCM)': {'Median': '9.999'}, 'Etch Reflected RF Power (W)': {'Median': '0.000'}, 'DC Current Current  (mA)': {'Median': '0.000'}, 'Depo Gas 1 Actual Flow (SCCM)': {'Median': '0.000'}, 'Depo Gas 2 Actual Flow (SCCM)': {'Median': '0.000'}, 'Chamber Pressure': {'Median': '2.7e-004'}, 'Etch Suppressor Voltage (V)': {'Median': '500.854'}, 'DC Current Voltage (V)': {'Median': '0.000'}, 'Etch Gas 1 Actual Flow (SCCM)': {'Median': '9.995'}, 'Etch Gas 3 Actual Flow (SCCM)': {'Median': '0.051'}, 'Etch Gas 2 Actual Flow (SCCM)': {'Median': '9.998'}}, 'stepname': None, 'runtime': None, 'steptime': None, 'tiltangle': None, 'stepsendby': None, 'champress': None}, '6': {'ProcStat': {'Etch PBN Filament (A)': {'Median': '0.099'}, 'Etch Source Magnet (A)': {'Median': '0.000'}, 'Etch Forward RF Power (W)': {'Median': '0.000'}, 'DC Current Power (W)': {'Median': '0.000'}, 'Etch Beam Current (mA)': {'Median': '2.716'}, 'Etch Suppressor Current (mA)': {'Median': '0.000'}, 'DC Current Impedance': {'Median': '0.000'}, 'Etch PBN Body (A)': {'Median': '0.000'}, 'Etch Beam Voltage (V)': {'Median': '1.740'}, 'Etch PBN Gas Actual Flow (SCCM)': {'Median': '0.000'}, 'Etch Reflected RF Power (W)': {'Median': '0.000'}, 'DC Current Current  (mA)': {'Median': '0.000'}, 'Depo Gas 1 Actual Flow (SCCM)': {'Median': '0.000'}, 'Depo Gas 2 Actual Flow (SCCM)': {'Median': '0.000'}, 'Chamber Pressure': {'Median': '3.7e-006'}, 'Etch Suppressor Voltage (V)': {'Median': '3.754'}, 'DC Current Voltage (V)': {'Median': '0.000'}, 'Etch Gas 1 Actual Flow (SCCM)': {'Median': '0.000'}, 'Etch Gas 3 Actual Flow (SCCM)': {'Median': '0.053'}, 'Etch Gas 2 Actual Flow (SCCM)': {'Median': '0.000'}}, 'stepname': None, 'runtime': None, 'steptime': None, 'tiltangle': None, 'stepsendby': None, 'champress': None}, '7': {'ProcStat': {'Etch PBN Filament (A)': {'Median': '55.834'}, 'Etch Source Magnet (A)': {'Median': '0.348'}, 'Etch Forward RF Power (W)': {'Median': '536.000'}, 'DC Current Power (W)': {'Median': '0.000'}, 'Etch Beam Current (mA)': {'Median': '161.011'}, 'Etch Suppressor Current (mA)': {'Median': '4.688'}, 'DC Current Impedance': {'Median': '0.000'}, 'Etch PBN Body (A)': {'Median': '0.486'}, 'Etch Beam Voltage (V)': {'Median': '299.835'}, 'Etch PBN Gas Actual Flow (SCCM)': {'Median': '6.999'}, 'Etch Reflected RF Power (W)': {'Median': '0.000'}, 'DC Current Current  (mA)': {'Median': '0.000'}, 'Depo Gas 1 Actual Flow (SCCM)': {'Median': '0.000'}, 'Depo Gas 2 Actual Flow (SCCM)': {'Median': '0.000'}, 'Chamber Pressure': {'Median': '2.3e-004'}, 'Etch Suppressor Voltage (V)': {'Median': '401.123'}, 'DC Current Voltage (V)': {'Median': '0.000'}, 'Etch Gas 1 Actual Flow (SCCM)': {'Median': '15.995'}, 'Etch Gas 3 Actual Flow (SCCM)': {'Median': '0.051'}, 'Etch Gas 2 Actual Flow (SCCM)': {'Median': '0.000'}}, 'stepname': None, 'runtime': None, 'steptime': None, 'tiltangle': None, 'stepsendby': None, 'champress': None}, '8': {'ProcStat': {'Etch PBN Filament (A)': {'Median': '56.128'}, 'Etch Source Magnet (A)': {'Median': '0.348'}, 'Etch Forward RF Power (W)': {'Median': '263.000'}, 'DC Current Power (W)': {'Median': '0.000'}, 'Etch Beam Current (mA)': {'Median': '100.098'}, 'Etch Suppressor Current (mA)': {'Median': '2.344'}, 'DC Current Impedance': {'Median': '0.000'}, 'Etch PBN Body (A)': {'Median': '0.498'}, 'Etch Beam Voltage (V)': {'Median': '299.835'}, 'Etch PBN Gas Actual Flow (SCCM)': {'Median': '6.999'}, 'Etch Reflected RF Power (W)': {'Median': '0.000'}, 'DC Current Current  (mA)': {'Median': '0.000'}, 'Depo Gas 1 Actual Flow (SCCM)': {'Median': '0.000'}, 'Depo Gas 2 Actual Flow (SCCM)': {'Median': '0.000'}, 'Chamber Pressure': {'Median': '2.3e-004'}, 'Etch Suppressor Voltage (V)': {'Median': '600.525'}, 'DC Current Voltage (V)': {'Median': '0.000'}, 'Etch Gas 1 Actual Flow (SCCM)': {'Median': '15.995'}, 'Etch Gas 3 Actual Flow (SCCM)': {'Median': '0.051'}, 'Etch Gas 2 Actual Flow (SCCM)': {'Median': '0.000'}}, 'stepname': None, 'runtime': None, 'steptime': None, 'tiltangle': None, 'stepsendby': None, 'champress': None}, '9': {'ProcStat': {'Etch PBN Filament (A)': {'Median': '55.782'}, 'Etch Source Magnet (A)': {'Median': '0.348'}, 'Etch Forward RF Power (W)': {'Median': '267.000'}, 'DC Current Power (W)': {'Median': '0.000'}, 'Etch Beam Current (mA)': {'Median': '100.220'}, 'Etch Suppressor Current (mA)': {'Median': '4.688'}, 'DC Current Impedance': {'Median': '0.000'}, 'Etch PBN Body (A)': {'Median': '0.494'}, 'Etch Beam Voltage (V)': {'Median': '299.927'}, 'Etch PBN Gas Actual Flow (SCCM)': {'Median': '6.999'}, 'Etch Reflected RF Power (W)': {'Median': '0.000'}, 'DC Current Current  (mA)': {'Median': '0.000'}, 'Depo Gas 1 Actual Flow (SCCM)': {'Median': '0.000'}, 'Depo Gas 2 Actual Flow (SCCM)': {'Median': '0.000'}, 'Chamber Pressure': {'Median': '2.7e-004'}, 'Etch Suppressor Voltage (V)': {'Median': '600.403'}, 'DC Current Voltage (V)': {'Median': '0.000'}, 'Etch Gas 1 Actual Flow (SCCM)': {'Median': '15.995'}, 'Etch Gas 3 Actual Flow (SCCM)': {'Median': '0.053'}, 'Etch Gas 2 Actual Flow (SCCM)': {'Median': '0.000'}}, 'stepname': None, 'runtime': None, 'steptime': None, 'tiltangle': None, 'stepsendby': None, 'champress': None}}}, 'PM2 (DLCXPFCA)_1': {'Steps': {'1': {'runtime': '05Dec16 00:45:24', 'steptime': '00:00:30.000'}, '2': {'runtime': '05Dec16 00:46:10', 'steptime': '00:06:00.000'}, '3': {'runtime': '05Dec16 00:50:30', 'steptime': '00:00:30.000'}}}}, 'Header': {'Header': {'processname': 'PM3_ARO2_Ni35A_fillin_2AD4.prc', 'runstart': None, 'datafile': None, 'schedule': None, 'rundate': None, 'waferid': None, 'user': None}}, 'Tool': 'DLCx04'}}
```

Right now I am using this code to get them one by one:

```
dict['Result']['Path']
```

And this code to get a single dictionary inside the main dict:

```
import csv
my_dict = {'processname': 'PM3_A3_ArN2-0deg_ArO2-0deg_Ar-55deg_Ar-70deg_Trial9.prc', 'runstart': '18:20:09', 'datafile': '2017-01-10_021_A1A', 'schedule': 'RUN1 PALMER', 'rundate': '2017-01-10 (Y M D)', 'waferid': '2017-01-10_021_A1A', 'user': 'Dev-B'}
shit = "C:\\Users\\rhipo7187970\\Desktop\\shit.csv"

f = open(shit,'wb')
w = csv.DictWriter(f,my_dict.keys())
w.fieldnames

headers = {} 
for n in w.fieldnames:
    headers[n] = n
w.writerow(headers)
w.writerow(my_dict)

f.close()
```

Any comment or suggestion function or script that I can use for reference. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I write a Python dictionary to a csv file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10373247/how-do-i-write-a-python-dictionary-to-a-csv-file)

Comment: it would be the same but in my case am having multiple instance of dictionary inside my main dictionary. And also is that possbile if I can use fileopen rather than withopen because our application is only using python 2.5 version