# Dictionary to CSV

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

Trying to populate a CSV file using a dictionary.

Here's the code I'm trying:

```
import csv

my_dict = {'App 1': 'App id1', 'App 2': 'App id2', 'App 3': 'App id3'}
with open('test.csv', 'w') as f:
    fieldnames = ['Application Name', 'Application ID']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerows(my_dict)
```

With this code it was only creating a csv file with the header.

I'm looking for a similar output:

[image]

Comment: Nice try!  Keep it up!  Is there a question you need answered?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I write a Python dictionary to a csv file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10373247/how-do-i-write-a-python-dictionary-to-a-csv-file)

Comment: Thanks Alan. The answer by @Moses helped me a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to reformat your data into a list of dicts such that keys and values from the old dict are placed as values against the fieldnames in new dicts:

```
my_dict = {'App 1': 'App id1', 'App 2': 'App id2', 'App 3': 'App id3'}
with open('test.csv', 'w') as f:
    fieldnames = ['Application Name', 'Application ID']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()
    data = [dict(zip(fieldnames, [k, v])) for k, v in my_dict.items()]
    writer.writerows(data)
```

Comment: Thanks! This almost solved my problem. However, I get an empty row after every item from my dictionary in the csv file. Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: @Raj Pretty common problem, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3348460/csv-file-written-with-python-has-blank-lines-between-each-row

Comment: Thanks a lot @Moses

Answer (score 3):

You can also do this without an import and fewer lines of code:

```
my_dict = {'App 1': 'App id1', 'App 2': 'App id2', 'App 3': 'App id3'}
with open('test.csv', 'w') as f:
    f.write('Application Name, Application ID\n')
    for key in my_dict.keys():
        f.write("%s,%s\n"%(key,my_dict[key]))
```