# how to save val_loss and val_acc in Keras

Tags: python, keras

I have trouble with recording 'val_loss' and 'val_acc' in Keras. 'loss' and 'acc' are easy because they always recorded in history of model.fit.

'val_loss' is recorded if validation is enabled in `fit`, and `val_acc` is recorded if validation and accuracy monitoring are enabled. But what does this mean?

My node is `model.fit(train_data, train_labels,epochs = 64,batch_size = 10,shuffle = True,validation_split = 0.2, callbacks=[history])`.

As you see, I use 5-fold cross-validation and shuffle the data. In this case, how can I enable `validation` in `fit` to record 'val_loss' and 'val_acc'?

Thanks

Comment: What I don't understand most is that this information is automatically printed on the screen every time and is the info that every user cares the most. Why Keras doesn't have a user-friendly method to store them in a file???

Comment: Take a look at [CSVLogger](https://keras.io/callbacks/#csvlogger)?

Comment: what is `history` in your example?

Answer (score 5):

From Keras documentation, we have for `models.fit` method:

```
fit(x=None, y=None, 
    batch_size=None, 
    epochs=1, 
    verbose=1, 
    callbacks=None, 
    validation_split=0.0, validation_data=None, 
    shuffle=True, 
    class_weight=None, 
    sample_weight=None, 
    initial_epoch=0, 
    steps_per_epoch=None, 
    validation_steps=None
)
```

`'val_loss' is recorded if validation is enabled in fit, and val_accis recorded if validation and accuracy monitoring are enabled.` - This is from the **keras.callbacks.Callback()** object, if used for callbacks parameter in the above fit method.

Instead of using the history callback, which you've used, it can be used as follows:

```
    from keras.callbacks import Callback
    logs = Callback()
    model.fit(train_data, 
                train_labels,
                epochs = 64, 
                batch_size = 10,
                shuffle = True,
                validation_split = 0.2, 
                callbacks=[logs]
           )
```

'val_loss' is recorded if validation is enabled in `fit` means: when using the model.fit method you are using either the `validatoin_split` parameter or you use `validation_data` parameter `to specify the tuple (x_val, y_val) or tuple  (x_val, y_val, val_sample_weights) on which to evaluate the loss and any model metrics at the end of each epoch.` .

> **A History object.** Its History.history attribute is a record of
> training loss values and metrics values at successive epochs, as well
> as validation loss values and validation metrics values (if
> applicable). - **Keras Documentation** ( Return value for model.fit method)

You are using the History callback, in your model as follows:

```
model.fit(train_data, 
            train_labels,
            epochs = 64,
            batch_size = 10,
            shuffle = True,
            validation_split = 0.2, 
            callbacks=[history]
       )
```

**history.history** will output a dictionary for you with the : `loss`, `acc`, `val_loss` and `val_acc`, if you use a variable for saving model.fit like below:

```
history = model.fit(
     train_data, 
     train_labels,
     epochs = 64,
     batch_size = 10,
     shuffle = True,
     validation_split = 0.2, 
     callbacks=[history]
)
history.history
```

The output will be like the following:

```
{'val_loss': [14.431451635814849,
              14.431451635814849,
              14.431451635814849,
              14.431451635814849,
              14.431451635814849,
              14.431451635814849,
              14.431451635814849,
              14.431451635814849,
              14.431451635814849,
              14.431451635814849],
 'val_acc':  [0.1046428571712403,
              0.1046428571712403,
              0.1046428571712403,
              0.1046428571712403,
              0.1046428571712403,
              0.1046428571712403,
              0.1046428571712403,
              0.1046428571712403,
              0.1046428571712403,
              0.1046428571712403],
 'loss': [14.555215610322499,
          14.555215534028553,
          14.555215548560733,
          14.555215588524229,
          14.555215592157273,
          14.555215581258137,
          14.555215575808571,
          14.55521561940511,
          14.555215563092913,
          14.555215624854679],
 'acc': [0.09696428571428571,
         0.09696428571428571,
         0.09696428571428571,
         0.09696428571428571,
         0.09696428571428571,
         0.09696428571428571,
         0.09696428571428571,
         0.09696428571428571,
         0.09696428571428571,
         0.09696428571428571]}
```

You can save the data both by using `csvlogger` like below as given in the comments or by using the longer method of writing a dictionary to a csv file as given here [writing a dictionary to a csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10373247/how-do-i-write-a-python-dictionary-to-a-csv-file#10373268)

```
csv_logger = CSVLogger('training.log')
model.fit(X_train, Y_train, callbacks=[csv_logger])
```

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE:  The `val_accuracy` dictionary key seems to no longer work today.  No idea why, but I removed that code from here despite the OP asking how to log it (also, loss is what actually matters for comparison of cross-validation results).

Using Python 3.7 and Tensorflow 2.0, the following worked for me, after much searching, guessing, and failing repeatedly.  I started with someone else's script to get what I needed written to a `.json` file; it produces one such `.json` file per training run showing the validation loss per epoch so you can see how the model converged (or did not); accuracy is logged but not as a performance metric.

**NOTE:**  You need to fill in `yourTrainDir`, `yourTrainingData`, `yourValidationData`, `yourOptimizer`, `yourLossFunctionFromKerasOrElsewhere`, `yourNumberOfEpochs`, etc. to enable this code to run:

```
import numpy as np
import os
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping, ModelCheckpoint, LambdaCallback
import json
model.compile(
    optimizer=yourOptimizer,
    loss=yourLossFunctionFromKerasOrElsewhere()
    )

# create a custom callback to enable future cross-validation efforts
yourTrainDir = os.getcwd() + '/yourOutputFolderName/'
uniqueID = np.random.randint(999999) # To distinguish validation runs by saved JSON name
epochValidationLog = open(
    yourTrainDir +
    'val_log_per_epoch_' +
    '{}_'.format(uniqueID) +
    '.json',
    mode='wt',
    buffering=1
    )
ValidationLogsCallback = LambdaCallback(
    on_epoch_end = lambda epoch,
        logs: epochValidationLog.write(
            json.dumps(
                {
                    'oneIndexedEpoch': epoch + 1,
                    'Validationloss': logs['val_loss']
                }
                ) + '\n'
            ),
    on_train_end = lambda logs: epochValidationLog.close()
    )

# set up the list of callbacks
callbacksList = [
    ValidationLogsCallback,
    EarlyStopping(patience=40, verbose=1),
    ]
results = model.fit(
    x=yourTrainingData,
    steps_per_epoch=len(yourTrainingData),
    validation_data=yourValidationData,
    validation_steps=len(yourValidationData),
    epochs=yourNumberOfEpochs,
    verbose=1,
    callbacks=callbacksList
    )
```

This produces a JSON file in `TrainDir` folder recording validation loss and accuracy for each training epoch as its own dictionary-like item.  Note that the epoch number is indexed to start at `1` so it matches the output of tensorflow, not the actual index in Python.

I am outputting to .JSON file but it could be anything.  Here is my code for analyzing the JSON files produced; I could have put it all in one script but did not.

```
import os
from pathlib import Path
import json

currentDirectory = os.getcwd()
outFileName = 'CVResults.json'
outFile = open(outFileName, mode='wt')
validationLogPaths = Path().glob('val_log_per_epoch_*.json')

# Necessary list to detect short unique IDs for each training session
stringDecimalDigits = [
    '1',
    '2',
    '3',
    '4',
    '5',
    '6',
    '7',
    '8',
    '9',
    '0'
]
setStringDecimalDigits = set(stringDecimalDigits)
trainingSessionsList = []

# Load the JSON files into memory to allow reading.
for validationLogFile in validationLogPaths:
    trainingUniqueIDCandidate = str(validationLogFile)[18:21]

    # Pad unique IDs with fewer than three digits with zeros at front
    thirdPotentialDigitOfUniqueID = trainingUniqueIDCandidate[2]
    if setStringDecimalDigits.isdisjoint(thirdPotentialDigitOfUniqueID):
        secondPotentialDigitOfUniqueID = trainingUniqueIDCandidate[1]
        if setStringDecimalDigits.isdisjoint(secondPotentialDigitOfUniqueID):
            trainingUniqueID = '00' + trainingUniqueIDCandidate[:1]
        else:
            trainingUniqueID = '0' + trainingUniqueIDCandidate[:2]
    else:
        trainingUniqueID = trainingUniqueIDCandidate
    trainingSessionsList.append((trainingUniqueID, validationLogFile))
trainingSessionsList.sort(key=lambda x: x[0])

# Analyze and export cross-validation results
for replicate in range(len(dict(trainingSessionsList).keys())):
    validationLogFile = trainingSessionsList[replicate][1]
    fileOpenForReading = open(
        validationLogFile, mode='r', buffering=1
    )

    with fileOpenForReading as openedFile:
        jsonValidationData = [json.loads(line) for line in openedFile]

    bestEpochResultsDict = {}
    oneIndexedEpochsList = []
    validationLossesList = []
    for line in range(len(jsonValidationData)):
        tempDict = jsonValidationData[line]
        oneIndexedEpochsList.append(tempDict['oneIndexedEpoch'])
        validationLossesList.append(tempDict['Validationloss'])
    trainingStopIndex = min(
        range(len(validationLossesList)),
        key=validationLossesList.__getitem__
    )
    bestEpochResultsDict['Integer_unique_ID'] = trainingSessionsList[replicate][0]
    bestEpochResultsDict['Min_val_loss'] = validationLossesList[trainingStopIndex]
    bestEpochResultsDict['Last_train_epoch'] = oneIndexedEpochsList[trainingStopIndex]
    outFile.write(json.dumps(bestEpochResultsDict, sort_keys=True) + '\n')

outFile.close()
```

This last block of code creates a JSON summarizing what is in `CVResults.json` produced above:

```
from pathlib import Path
import json
import os
import statistics

outFile = open("CVAnalysis.json", mode='wt')
CVResultsPath = sorted(Path().glob('*CVResults.json'))
if len(CVResultsPath) > 1:
    print('\nPlease analyze only one CVResults.json file at at time.')
    userAnswer = input('\nI understand only one will be analyzed: y or n')
    if (userAnswer == 'y') or (userAnswer == 'Y'):
        print('\nAnalyzing results in file {}:'.format(str(CVResultsPath[0])))

# Load the first CVResults.json file into memory to allow reading.
CVResultsFile = CVResultsPath[0]
fileOpenForReading = open(
    CVResultsFile, mode='r', buffering=1
)

outFile.write(
    'Analysis of cross-validation results tabulated in file {}'.format(
        os.getcwd()
    ) +
    str(CVResultsFile) +
    ':\n\n'
)

with fileOpenForReading as openedFile:
    jsonCVResultsData = [json.loads(line) for line in openedFile]

minimumValidationLossesList = []
trainedOneIndexedEpochsList = []
for line in range(len(jsonCVResultsData)):
    tempDict = jsonCVResultsData[line]
    minimumValidationLossesList.append(tempDict['Min_val_loss'])
    trainedOneIndexedEpochsList.append(tempDict['Last_train_epoch'])
outFile.write(
    '\nTrained validation losses: ' +
    json.dumps(minimumValidationLossesList) +
    '\n'
)
outFile.write(
    '\nTraining epochs required: ' +
    json.dumps(trainedOneIndexedEpochsList) +
    '\n'
)
outFile.write(
    '\n\nMean trained validation loss: ' +
    str(round(statistics.mean(minimumValidationLossesList), 4)) +
    '\n'
)
outFile.write(
    'Median of mean trained validation losses per session: ' +
    str(round(statistics.median(minimumValidationLossesList), 4)) +
    '\n'
)
outFile.write(
    '\n\nMean training epochs required: ' +
    str(round(statistics.mean(trainedOneIndexedEpochsList), 1)) +
    '\n'
)
outFile.write(
    'Median of mean training epochs required per session: ' +
    str(round(statistics.median(trainedOneIndexedEpochsList), 1)) +
    '\n'
)
outFile.close()
```

Comment: I generalized the optimizer and the loss function in the first block of code.  So you need to select these and implement them specifically; if attempting to run this it will break.

Comment: I realize this code is extremely fragile; in fact, the so-called `uniqueID` often gets over-written so I lose hours of time for a validation replicate each time that happens.  I am not an excellent coder, so please leave out comments about anything other than raw utility.

Comment: Possibly simpler method of logging results could be to create
```class lossLogger(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def __init__(self, fileName):
        self.fileName = fileName
        self.json_log = open(self.fileName+'.json', mode='w+', buffering=1)
        
    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
        self.json_log.write(json.dumps('epoch {}: '.format(epoch) + str(logs)) + '\n' )
        
    def on_train_end(self, logs=None):
        self.json_log.close()
```

Comment: I recommend setting one's validation data manually for many reasons.  This bug might have been fixed by now, but the concept of validation and testing in the world of non-linear modeling leaves much theory to be desired:  https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/37840

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to save the data of `val_loss` and `val_acc` using the [ModelCheckpoint](https://keras.io/callbacks/) class of Keras.

```
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint

checkpointer = ModelCheckpoint(filepath='yourmodelname.hdf5', 
                               monitor='val_loss', 
                               verbose=1, 
                               save_best_only=False)

history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=100, validation_split=0.02, callbacks=[checkpointer])

history.history.keys()

# output
# dict_keys(['val_loss', 'val_mae', 'val_acc', 'loss', 'mae', 'acc'])
```

An important point, if you omit the `validation_split` property, you will only get the values of `loss`, `mae` and `acc`.

Hope this helps!