# Python 3 - Load JSON data into my .csv -file

Tags: json, python-3.x, csv, dictionary

I actually try to write JSON in a data.csv file. I tried following solution from stackoverflow:
[How do I write a Python dictionary to a csv file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10373247/how-do-i-write-a-python-dictionary-to-a-csv-file)

So I come up with these:

```
with open("data/dataGold.csv", 'w') as f:
    w = csv.DictWriter(f, ['data']['user']['repositories']['nodes'], extrasaction='ignore')
    w.writeheader()
    w.writerow(response)
    w.writerow([data['data']['user']['repositories']['nodes']['name'],
              data['data']['user']['repositories']['nodes']['forkCount'],
              data['data']['user']['repositories']['nodes']['issues']])
```

My response variable of type 'dict' is:

```
{'data': {'user': {'name': 'Markus Goldstein',
                   'repositories': {'nodes': [{'forkCount': 0,
                                               'issues': {'totalCount': 0},
                                               'name': 'repache'},
                                              {'forkCount': 4,
                                               'issues': {'totalCount': 3},
                                               'name': 'nf-hishape'},
                                              {'forkCount': 4,
                                               'issues': {'totalCount': 7},
                                               'name': 'ip-countryside'},
                                              {'forkCount': 42,
                                               'issues': {'totalCount': 29},
                                               'name': 'bonesi'},
                                              {'forkCount': 13,
                                               'issues': {'totalCount': 3},
                                               'name': 'rapidminer-anomalydetection'},
                                              {'forkCount': 0,
                                               'issues': {'totalCount': 0},
                                               'name': 'rapidminer-studio'}]}}}}
```

There is a TypeError that says no indices allowed. I think that is because I used ['data']['user']['repositories']['nodes'].

The solution I posted the link above works becaus no nested Dict/JSON. So I have no idea how to do in my case with the nested Dict/JSON

So my goal is a CSV that contains **name, forkCount and issues** as header. And the next lines are the values of the different repo's.

May someone can help me and sorry for my bad english -.- Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given below should work fine,

1] The extra loop that I have written changes your structure to one that removes the dictionary under **issues** and stores value of **total_counts** under **issues** so that the CSV comes out clean.

2] I am using **deepcopy** here because I do not want to modify the original data structure, thus instead of using a reference i am using deepcopy of it.

3] Type casting `wt_csv[0].keys()` to **list** as `.keys()` function returns **dict_keys** in python 3 and not a list

```
import csv
import json
import copy

i_dict = {'data': {'user': {'name': 'Markus Goldstein',
                           'repositories': {'nodes': [{'forkCount': 0,
                                                       'issues': {'totalCount': 0},
                                                       'name': 'repache'},
                                                      {'forkCount': 4,
                                                       'issues': {'totalCount': 3},
                                                       'name': 'nf-hishape'},
                                                      {'forkCount': 4,
                                                       'issues': {'totalCount': 7},
                                                       'name': 'ip-countryside'},
                                                      {'forkCount': 42,
                                                       'issues': {'totalCount': 29},
                                                       'name': 'bonesi'},
                                                      {'forkCount': 13,
                                                       'issues': {'totalCount': 3},
                                                       'name': 'rapidminer-anomalydetection'},
                                                      {'forkCount': 0,
                                                       'issues': {'totalCount': 0},
                                                       'name': 'rapidminer-studio'}]}}}}


wt_csv = copy.deepcopy(i_dict['data']['user']['repositories']['nodes'])

for wc in wt_csv:
    wc['issues'] = wc['issues']['totalCount']

with open('dataGold.csv', 'w') as output_file:
    dict_writer = csv.DictWriter(output_file, fieldnames=list(wt_csv[0].keys()))
    dict_writer.writeheader()
    dict_writer.writerows(wt_csv)
```

Let me know in comments if something is unclear.

Comment: That actually works perfect :) Thank you :) And because of your clear description, I understood all.

Answer (score 0):

```
Markus = {'data': {'user': {'name': 'Markus Goldstein',
                   'repositories': {'nodes': [{'forkCount': 0,
                                               'issues': {'totalCount': 0},
                                               'name': 'repache'},
                                              {'forkCount': 4,
                                               'issues': {'totalCount': 3},
                                               'name': 'nf-hishape'},
                                              {'forkCount': 4,
                                               'issues': {'totalCount': 7},
                                               'name': 'ip-countryside'},
                                              {'forkCount': 42,
                                               'issues': {'totalCount': 29},
                                               'name': 'bonesi'},
                                              {'forkCount': 13,
                                               'issues': {'totalCount': 3},
                                               'name': 'rapidminer-anomalydetection'},
                                              {'forkCount': 0,
                                               'issues': {'totalCount': 0},
                                               'name': 'rapidminer-studio'}]}}}}

with open('Markus.csv', 'w') as markus:
    print ('name,forkCount,issues', file=markus)
    for node in Markus['data']['user']['repositories']['nodes']:
        print ('{},{},{}'.format(node['name'], node['forkCount'], node['issues']['totalCount']), file=markus)
```

- The first `print` statement outputs the header line to the csv file.
- The for loop arranges to unpack items from the dictionary.
- The second `print` statement arranges to output each unpacked item to the csv file.

The result is this.

```
name,forkCount,issues
repache,0,0
nf-hishape,4,3
ip-countryside,4,7
bonesi,42,29
rapidminer-anomalydetection,13,3
rapidminer-studio,0,0
```

Comment: Thank you too. It works also, but I prefer the accepted solution :)

Answer (score 0):

so considering you're analyzing RapidMiner usage, you may also choose to just use RapidMiner Text Processing: [image]

here's the XML:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<process version="8.0.001">
  <context>
    <input/>
    <output/>
    <macros/>
  </context>
  <operator activated="true" class="process" compatibility="8.0.001" expanded="true" name="Process">
    <process expanded="true">
      <operator activated="true" class="text:create_document" compatibility="7.5.000" expanded="true" height="68" name="Create Document" width="90" x="45" y="34">
        <parameter key="text" value="{&#10;  &quot;data&quot;: {&#10;    &quot;user&quot;: {&#10;      &quot;name&quot;: &quot;Markus Goldstein&quot;,&#10;      &quot;repositories&quot;: {&#10;        &quot;nodes&quot;: [&#10;          {&#10;            &quot;forkCount&quot;: 0,&#10;            &quot;issues&quot;: {&#10;              &quot;totalCount&quot;: 0&#10;            },&#10;            &quot;name&quot;: &quot;repache&quot;&#10;          },&#10;          {&#10;            &quot;forkCount&quot;: 4,&#10;            &quot;issues&quot;: {&#10;              &quot;totalCount&quot;: 3&#10;            },&#10;            &quot;name&quot;: &quot;nf-hishape&quot;&#10;          },&#10;          {&#10;            &quot;forkCount&quot;: 4,&#10;            &quot;issues&quot;: {&#10;              &quot;totalCount&quot;: 7&#10;            },&#10;            &quot;name&quot;: &quot;ip-countryside&quot;&#10;          },&#10;          {&#10;            &quot;forkCount&quot;: 42,&#10;            &quot;issues&quot;: {&#10;              &quot;totalCount&quot;: 29&#10;            },&#10;            &quot;name&quot;: &quot;bonesi&quot;&#10;          },&#10;          {&#10;            &quot;forkCount&quot;: 13,&#10;            &quot;issues&quot;: {&#10;              &quot;totalCount&quot;: 3&#10;            },&#10;            &quot;name&quot;: &quot;rapidminer-anomalydetection&quot;&#10;          },&#10;          {&#10;            &quot;forkCount&quot;: 0,&#10;            &quot;issues&quot;: {&#10;              &quot;totalCount&quot;: 0&#10;            },&#10;            &quot;name&quot;: &quot;rapidminer-studio&quot;&#10;          }&#10;        ]&#10;      }&#10;    }&#10;  }&#10;}"
        />
      </operator>
      <operator activated="true" class="text:json_to_data" compatibility="7.5.000" expanded="true" height="82" name="JSON To Data" width="90" x="179" y="34" />
      <connect from_op="Create Document" from_port="output" to_op="JSON To Data" to_port="documents 1" />
      <connect from_op="JSON To Data" from_port="example set" to_port="result 1" />
      <portSpacing port="source_input 1" spacing="0" />
      <portSpacing port="sink_result 1" spacing="0" />
      <portSpacing port="sink_result 2" spacing="0" />
    </process>
  </operator>
</process>
```