# python dictionary to csv with horizontal orientation

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

I have a simple python dictionary in format:

```
{"key1":1,"key2":42,"key3":"foo"}
```

And would like to store in a csv file in which the keys are the headers and the values the cell values of the second row:

```
| "key1"  | "Key2" | "key3" |  
| 1       | 42     | "foo" |
```

the csv file will only have 2 rows.

I think it is possible using csv and python but can't find the correct approach (should be so easy). My rows/columns are always swapped.

Comment: Maybe you can find what you need in this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10373247/how-do-i-write-a-python-dictionary-to-a-csv-file

Comment: please let me know if I should mark as duplicate and remove or leave this Q here.

Comment: @RutgerHofste, I suggest you look at the answers and if you think they are straightforward to derive from the dup then accept the dup. This question does IMO have a small twist in that the input is neither a list of dictionaries, nor a dictionary with list values.

Comment: do you want a csv or pipe separated?

Comment: TLDR: csv is fine for now. the objective is to ingest a geopackage into google bigquery. I split up the features in the geopackage and convert the geometry to Well Known Text. A fancier approach would use Apache Beam but I will stcik to CSV for now. CSVs are uploaded to google cloud and bigquery can process them in parallel.(also, I spent too long reading Apache beam docs today that I could't figure out the easy stuff anymore.)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you `dict` name as `d`

```
pd.Series(d).to_frame().T
Out[55]: 
  key1 key2 key3
0    1   42  foo
#pd.Series(d).to_frame().T.to_csv()
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([d])

df.to_csv('out.csv', index=False)

print(df)

   key1  key2 key3
0     1    42  foo
```

Notice the `pd.DataFrame` constructor accepts a `list` of dictionaries. Here the list happens to have only one dictionary, but this is sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Obvious answers have already been posted. Give a shot at numpy. Also, it will not regard the ordering.

```
import numpy as np
d={"key1":1,"key2":42,"key3":"foo"}
a=np.array([d.keys()])
b=np.array([d.values()])
x=np.concatenate([a,b],0)

np.savetxt('x.csv',x,delimiter=',',fmt='%s')
```

Answer (score 0):

you can give it a try like this too

```
d = {"key1":1,"key2":42,"key3":"foo"}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient='index').T
print(df)
  key1 key2 key3
0    1   42  foo
```