# Turn a single entry in a dictionary of dictionaries into a dataframe where keys are the columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

Given a dictionary such as:

```
records = {0:{'name':'John', 'salary':'5000'}, 1:{'name':'Bob', 'salary':'3500'}}
```

If I want to get and store (in csv) a dataframe such as:

```
name  salary
John   5000
```

By using records[0] as a way to access the dictionary inside, how would I do that?

I have tried:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(records[0], index=[0])

df= pd.DataFrame(list(records[0].values()), columns=list(records[0].keys()))

df= pd.DataFrame.from_dict(records[key], orient='columns')
```

But none of them worked as intended (2nd one gave me an error, 1st and last have just one column)

Comment: A dictionary isn't always ordered in a particular way.  Are you ordering it a certain way prior to selecting the data you need?  How is the original dictionary getting created? 
 Will you always need only the first value?

Comment: Use pandas to make dataframe from csv file > turn to dict > start loop:: use for key in dict: to loop over each "row" > add two fields > append row to an initially empty csv file > end loop

Comment: Why do you need pandas to write to the csv file?  You can just write the dictionary to the csv:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10373247/how-do-i-write-a-python-dictionary-to-a-csv-file

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.from_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html) with `orient='index'`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(records, orient='index')
print (df)
   name salary
0  John   5000
1   Bob   3500
```

EDIT - For first value of `record` pass to nested list:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([records[0]])
print (df)
   name salary
0  John   5000
```

Comment: I just want to turn the first entry to a dataframe. I dont want to turn both, I already know how to do that.

Comment: I didnt want to turn it all to a dataframe because I am dealing with a dictionary with thousands of entries and I will be doing this operation every step while iterating over the dictionary. The dictionary comes from a csv file that's larger than 500mb, so turning the entire thing to a dataframe and indexing at every iteration will take too much time I think.

Comment: @MohamadMoustafa Are you turning the entire file into an csv sheet or only a subset? You're working with a dictionary so you can just iterate through the dict and keep only what you want before turning it into a dataframe. (Or read the csv line and put what you want into the dataframe).

Comment: use this to turn only the first entry - `pd.DataFrame.from_dict([records[0]], orient='columns')`

Comment: I use to_dict to turn entire dataframe created using csv file to dict. I then loop over each "row" (dict inside dict) , make changes, turn "row" to dataframe, and append it to empty csv file.

Comment: @nag I am not using a static number,I use key. This is inside a ```for key in dict:``` loop.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a combination of [`DataFrame.from_dict()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html)  and  [`DataFrame.T`](http://%20https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html) :

```
records = {0:{'name':'John', 'salary':'5000'}, 1:{'name':'Bob', 'salary':'3500'}}
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(records).T
```

**Output**

```
+----+-------+--------+
|    | name  | salary |
+----+-------+--------+
| 0  | John  |   5000 |
| 1  | Bob   |   3500 |
+----+-------+--------+
```

**EDIT**
To get just the first record

```
df[df.index==0]
```

```
+----+-------+--------+
|    | name  | salary |
+----+-------+--------+
| 0  | John  |   5000 |
+----+-------+--------+
```

Comment: nice output representation.