# Save Dictonary into CSV by value

Tags: python-3.x

I have following dictionaries and wanted to save the values to appropriate columns

```
my_dict1= {'key1':'Yes','key2':'No', 'key3':12, 'key4':'Enabled', 'key5':'Single'}
my_dict2= {'key1':'Yes','key3':4, 'key4':'Disabled'}
```

I would like to save dictionary into CSV file such that CVS should like like

```
key1 | key2 | key3 | key4 | key5
Yes  | No   | 12   | Enabled | Single
Yes  | -   | 4    | Disabled | -
```

Comment: Duplicate:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10373247/how-do-i-write-a-python-dictionary-to-a-csv-file

Comment: Kindly note that key2 and key5 column does not have values in my_dict2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to normalize your `my_dict2` first. Below should work.

```py
import csv

my_dict1= {'key1':'Yes','key2':'No', 'key3':12, 'key4':'Enabled', 'key5':'Single'}
my_dict2= {'key1':'Yes','key3':4, 'key4':'Disabled'}

keys = my_dict1.keys()

for k in keys:
    if not k in my_dict2.keys():
        my_dict2[k] = 'NA'

with open('output.csv', 'w', newline='')  as file:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(file, keys)
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerows([my_dict1, my_dict2])
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be done very easily using **pandas** module.

```py
import pandas as pd

my_dict1= {'key1':'Yes','key2':'No', 'key3':12, 'key4':'Enabled', 'key5':'Single'}
my_dict2= {'key1':'Yes','key3':4, 'key4':'Disabled'}

data1 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(my_dict1,orient='index').T
data2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(my_dict2,orient='index').T

data = pd.merge(data1,data2,how='outer')

data.to_csv('output_data.csv',index=False)
```