# python adding index column when export dictionary object to CSV

Tags: python, dictionary

my dictionary is:

```
new_dict = {'H1': ['a1', 'a2', 'a3'], 'H2': ['b1', 'b2'], 'H3': ['c1']}
```

I'd like to export it in csv in such format:

[image]

my way of doing it now is

```
csv_rows = [{'Key': key, 'Value': addr} for key, value in new_dict.items() for addr in value]

with open('result.csv', 'w', newline = '') as f:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f, ('Key', 'Value'))
    writer.writerheader()
    writer.writerows(csv_rows)
```

which gives result in result.csv look like below

[image]

however the index column is missing. can anyone suggest how to add the index column in the csv? thanks

Comment: Yes, of course.  What has *your* research shown?

Comment: Use nested loops to iterate over the keys and then the values in the lists. Then use the `csv` module to write rows to the CSV file.

Comment: Please show what you tried. We'll help you fix it, we won't write it for you.

Comment: Refer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10373247/how-do-i-write-a-python-dictionary-to-a-csv-file

Comment: @HarishIyer That's very different.

Comment: hi all, updated with my original way of doing that. Could you please advise? thanks @Barmar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```py
import csv

data = {'H1': ['a1', 'a2', 'a3'], 'H2': ['b1', 'b2'], 'H3': ['c1']}
with open("C://Desktop/temp.csv", "w", newline='') as fp:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(fp, fieldnames=["index","Key","Value"])
    index = 0
    for Key in data.keys():
        for Value in data[Key]:
            writer.writerow({'index':index, "Key":Key, "Value":Value})
            index += 1
```

A few things:

- don't call a variable `dict` that's a reserved word/builtin
- This is a Windows implementation, so you may not need the `newline` part of the open, and you probably want to change that filename while you're at it.
- The `index` is a bit non-pythonic to me, I'd prefer using `enumerate`, but, because of your nested values pretty much mean that you'll need to count your own indexes.
- In the future, show your attempt to accomplish your task. SO is not a friendly place where you can get software written for you.  And, along these lines, your problem is not "Can it be done?"  because, of course it can.  Your question really should have been "How do I create a CSV from a `dict` with nested lists of values"

---

**EDIT**

With the addition to your code, the thing you are missing is the definition of the fieldnames in the `csv.DictWriter` class.  Then, you need to pass the index explicitly to the csv writer.  `enumerate` is a great and pythonic way to do this:

This is not as pretty, I feel, as the way that I did it above, because it has a lot of value packing and un-packing.  But, this does seem to have the results you're looking for.  I moved the `dict` comprehension to the last moment, so that you can capture that index on the final output.  You *could* iterate over the `csv_rows` and update the `dict`s to have an index, but I *am* doing that in that last step.  Anyway, at a minimum, I hope that you can gleem what we are trying to do here and maybe you'll find a simpler way to do what you need.

```py
csv_rows = [(key, addr) for key, value in data.items() for addr in value]

 with open('C://Desktop/result.csv', 'w', newline = '') as f:
     writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=('index','Key', 'Value'))
     writer.writeheader()
     writer.writerows({'index':ii, "Key":k, "Value":v} for ii,(k,v) in enumerate(csv_rows,1))
```

Comment: thanks! I followed your code but it has errors on this line of code: writer.writerow({'index':index, "Key":Key, "Value":Value}) error message: attributeerror: 'str' object has no attribute 'keys'. I also updated the questions with my original way of doing that.

Comment: revisiting my code, seems to run and create the file you're looking for. The error you've provided seems to imply that the for-loop is not able to find the `keys` method on the `data` dict.  I am certain that python `dict`s have a keys() method.  Would you doublecheck that your `data` is being initilized correctly?