# importing izip from itertools module gives NameError in Python 3.x

Tags: python, python-itertools

I am trying to import the izip module like so:

```
from itertools import izip
```

However after recently changing over from Python 2.7 to 3 - it doesn't seem to work.

I am trying to write to a csv file:

```
writer.writerows(izip(variable1,2))
```

But I have no luck. Still encounter an error.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

In Python 3 the built-in `zip` does the same job as `itertools.izip` in 2.X(returns an iterator instead of a list). The [`zip` implementation](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.5/Python/bltinmodule.c#L2445) is almost completely copy-pasted from the [old `izip`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v2.7.13/Modules/itertoolsmodule.c#L3491), just with a few names changed and pickle support added.

Here is a benchmark between `zip` in Python 2 and 3 and `izip` in Python 2:

[Python 2.7](https://ideone.com/Z735Gq):

```
from timeit import timeit

print(timeit('list(izip(xrange(100), xrange(100)))',
             'from itertools import izip',
             number=500000))

print(timeit('zip(xrange(100), xrange(100))', number=500000))
```

Output:

```
1.9288790226
1.2828938961
```

[Python 3](https://ideone.com/650rC7):

```
from timeit import timeit

print(timeit('list(zip(range(100), range(100)))', number=500000))
```

Output:

```
1.7653984297066927
```

In this case since `zip`'s arguments must support iteration you can not use 2 as its argument. So if you want to write 2 variable as a CSV row you can put them in a tuple or list:

```
writer.writerows((variable1,2))
```

Also from `itertools` you can import `zip_longest` as a more flexible function which you can use it on iterators with different size.

Comment: aargh - apparently I do not understand edit grace periods as well as I thought I did. now the edit logs are confusing

Answer (score 23):

One of the ways which helped me is:

```
try:
    from itertools import izip as zip
except ImportError: # will be 3.x series
    pass
```

Answer (score 17):

Use `zip` instead of `izip` directly in python 3, no need to import anything.

For further visit [here](https://github.com/nschloe/matplotlib2tikz/issues/20).

Comment: For further *what*? :)

Comment: For further understanding and looking at the patch where it was fixed. Maybe a good way to go. @bers

Comment: according to Raymond Hettinger izip is much faster and way efficient