# How to convert multiple text files to csv format in Python3?

Tags: python-3.x, csv

I have just over 2000 .txt files that I need to convert to .csv files. Each is sequentially labeled (i.e. nstar0001.txt, nstar0002.txt, etc...). I have searched multiple places for answers, but often the solutions are for Python2.x or use outdated libraries. Each star file has 7 columns of data that I want to label when converting to csv format.

Here is my most recent attempt:

```
import csv
import os
import itertools


##Convert all nstar####.txt files to csv
stars = int(input("Enter the TOTAL number of stars (including 'bad' stars):"))
k = 1
while k < stars + 1:
    if k < 10:
        q = 'nstar' + '0' + '0' + '0' + str(k) + '.txt'
        r = 'nstar' + '0' + '0' + '0' + str(k) + '.csv'
        with open(q, 'rb') as in_file:
            stripped = (line.strip() for line in in_file)
            lines = (line for line in stripped if line)
            grouped = itertools.izip(*[lines] * 7)
            with open(r, 'wb') as out_file:
                writer = csv.write(out_file)
                writer.writerow(('jd', 'mag', 'merr', 'id', 'cerr', 'serr', 'perr'))
                writer.writerows(grouped)
```

This was borrowed from another StackOverflow question and slightly modified to suit my needs. However, upon running I get

```
AttributeError: module 'itertools' has no attribute 'izip'
```

I know this loop only works for the first few files, but just wanted to get it working before running it for all files.

Comment: `izip` is in Python-2.x. Use `zip` on Python-3.x. This SO post may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32659552/izip-not-working-in-python-3-x or you can try this from github https://github.com/nschloe/matplotlib2tikz/issues/20

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use pandas. Something like this should work:

```
import pandas as pd

for i in range(5):
    fln = "nstar%04d" % i
    df = pd.read_csv(fln+".txt",delim_whitespace=True, header=None)
    hdr = ['jd', 'mag', 'merr', 'id', 'cerr', 'serr', 'perr']
    df.to_csv(fln+".csv", header=hdr, index=False)
```

Comment: Using that for loop starts the script searching for nstar0000.txt, but my data start at nstar0001.txt. How can I change that to start one higher. [Edit] Got it with a while loop. Thanks for the help! works like a charm.

Comment: Range will also take a start value: range(1,N) will do what you want.

Comment: What is the benefit of using that over a while loop?

Comment: Initialization, testing and incrementing of the loop counter is all done in one clear statement. That makes it easier to read and easier to maintain.