# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'float' in Python 3.6

Tags: python, types

```
avg = moving_average(Y, window_size=12).tolist()
residual = Y - avg
std = np.std(residual)
sigma=3

print({'standard_deviation': round(std, 3),
        'anomalies_dict': collections.OrderedDict([(index, y_i) for
                                                   index, y_i, avg_i in zip_longest(count(), Y, avg)
          if (y_i > avg_i + (sigma*std)) | (y_i < avg_i - (sigma*std))])})
```

Y --> Series of float elements

Upon running the above code, it's running fine on Python 2.7, but failing on 3.6.
The only change in above code from the 2.7 Version code is, I am using here zip_longest whereas I used izip in 2.7 code.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-37-acf40bad87e9>", line 8, in <module>
    index, y_i, avg_i in zip_longest(count(), Y, avg)

  File "<ipython-input-37-acf40bad87e9>", line 9, in <listcomp>
    if (y_i > avg_i + (sigma*std)) | (y_i < avg_i - (sigma*std))])})

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'float'
```

Need help on this.

Comment: `zip` in Python3 does the same job as `izip` in Python2 apparently. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32659552/izip-not-working-in-python-3-x

Answer (score 0):

You can use zip() function, just replace izip with zip, and the code should work.