# installing numpy for pypy: No module named setuptools

Tags: numpy, module, installation, pypy

When I try to set up numpy on windows with the command prompt with

```
C:\numpy>pypy setup.py install
```

I get:

```
ImportError: No module named setuptools
```

But setuptools seems to be installed, do I miss something?

```
>python -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools 

Requirement already up-to-date: setuptools in 
c:\users\p\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages
```

I also tried to install numpy with pypy3 instead of pypy2:

```
C:\numpy>pypy3 setup.py install
```

but then I get the following error (bear with me! :) )

```
C:\numpy>pypy3 setup.py install
Running from numpy source directory.
C:\pypy3-v5.10.1-win32\lib-python\3\distutils\dist.py:261: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'test_suite'
  warnings.warn(msg)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 285, in <module>
    setup_package()
  File "setup.py", line 277, in setup_package
    setup(**metadata)
  File "C:\numpy\numpy\distutils\core.py", line 135, in setup
    config = configuration()
  File "setup.py", line 178, in configuration
    config.add_subpackage('numpy')
  File "C:\numpy\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 1001, in add_subpackage
    caller_level = 2)
  File "C:\numpy\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 970, in get_subpackage
    caller_level = caller_level + 1)
  File "C:\numpy\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 907, in _get_configuration_from_setup_py
    config = setup_module.configuration(*args)
  File "numpy\setup.py", line 11, in configuration
    config.add_subpackage('core')
  File "C:\numpy\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 1001, in add_subpackage
    caller_level = 2)
  File "C:\numpy\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 970, in get_subpackage
    caller_level = caller_level + 1)
  File "C:\numpy\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 907, in _get_configuration_from_setup_py
    config = setup_module.configuration(*args)
  File "numpy\core\setup.py", line 726, in configuration
    from _parition_build import ffi
  File "numpy\core\_parition_build.py", line 87, in <module>
    PARTITION_DEFS += '\n' + generate_declarations()
  File "numpy\core\_parition_build.py", line 82, in generate_declarations
    for _suff, _type in itertools.izip(list_suff, list_type):
AttributeError: module 'itertools' has no attribute 'izip'
```

Comment: `itertools.izip` is a Py2 function, not in py3.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32659552/izip-not-working-in-python-3-x

Answer (score 2):

`python -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools` is installing setuptools for CPython.  You need to say `pypy -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools`.

You may have to say first `pypy -m ensurepip`, once.

Comment: `pypy3 -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools` says `/usr/bin/pypy3: No module named pip`

Comment: You need to run ``ensurepip`` once.  Updated my answer.