# Python, writing CSV file has extra blank rows

Tags: python, csv

I have a piece of python code which is supposed to open (or create) a CSV file and append a new row to the end of it. However, there is an extra blank line added between each entry. Is there a way to avoid this?

I have around 500 instances of the script which all access the same file, though (in theory) they should access the file at different times.

```
def writeBest(fileName, savePath, data):

    # Create a filename
    name = "BEST_" + fileName + ".csv"

    # Create the complete filename including the absolute path 
    completePath = os.path.join(savePath, fileName)

    # Check if directory exists
    if not os.path.exists(completePath):
        os.makedirs(completePath)

    completeName = os.path.join(completePath, name)

    # Write the data to a file
    theFile = open(completeName, 'wb')
    writer = csv.writer(theFile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    writer.writerow(data)

    # Close the file
    theFile.close()
```

Comment: What is data? which type?

Comment: If you want to add to the csv file I'd imagine you want to open it with the `ab` mode, not `wb`.

Comment: it needs to create the file if it doesnt exist

Comment: @ChrisHeadleand The `'a'` mode will create the file if it doesn't exist. (Test it yourself.) Anyway, can you show us a same of your `data` argument?

Comment: @ChrisHeadleand the w will overwrite a file if it already exists rather than add to it.

Comment: Can you tell us what `writer.dialect.lineterminator` is? It should be `'\r\n'` since you didn't specify a dialect (it'll default to `'excel'` in that case) but maybe it's not.

Comment: See the answer on this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3348460/csv-file-written-with-python-has-blank-lines-between-each-row/#53577233

Answer (score 3):

Problem answered through comments. The issue was using the `wb` mode not `ab` mode.

Comment: You might want to explain a bit more: it's not clear how this could solve your problem.  Opening the file with mode `"wb"` would clobber what was there before, not append but introduce extra blank lines.

Answer (score 0):

the 'b' option dose the trick for me, check the API doc: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?highlight=open#open