# In python 2.7 - How to read data from csv, reformat data, and write to new csv

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm a programing noob, and I'm stuck...  My goal is to open a csv file (an export from program A), reformat the data, and write it to a new csv file (for program B to import).  I know my code isn't pretty, though it works up until it writes to the new csv file.  It only writes the last row of data from the old csv.

```
import csv

print 'Enter file location or press enter for default location.'
aPath = raw_input('> ')  # user path to file
if aPath == '':
    aPath = '/default/path/to/file'  # default path
aFile = raw_input('Enter file name: ')  # user file name
if aFile == '':
    aFile = 'orginal.csv'  # default file name
myCSV = csv.DictReader(open(aPath + aFile, 'r'), delimiter=',')
print myCSV.fieldnames # verify fieldnames

for p in myCSV:
    w = csv.writer(open("output.csv", "w"))
    try:
        p = dict((k, v) for k, v in p.iteritems()
            if v.lower() != 'null')
    except AttributeError, e:
        print e
        print p
        raise Exception()
# reformats the columns of data for the output.csv
    pID = p.get('Last Name')[-4:]
    pName = p.get('Last Name')[:-4].strip() + ', ' + p.get('First Name')
    pDate = p.get('Start Time')[:-5]
    pBlank = p.get('')
    pCourse = p.get('Assigned Through')
    pScore = p.get('Score')[:-1]

# verifies the new columns
    print pID, pName, pDate, pBlank, pCourse, pBlank, pBlank, pScore

# NOT working...Only writes the last row of the orginal.csv to output.csv
    w.writerow([pID, pName, pDate, pBlank, pCourse, pBlank, pBlank, pScore])
```

Comment: Check your `w = csv.writer...` line. Are you sure it should be *inside* the `for` loop? This means the file is opened again and again and the row is overwritten again and again.

Comment: Thank you @Nanashi, that fix it; however I'm getting a blank row between each row with data.

Comment: Posting an answer to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following modified code should work:

```
import csv

print 'Enter file location or press enter for default location.'
aPath = raw_input('> ')  # user path to file
if aPath == '':
    aPath = '/default/path/to/file'  # default path
aFile = raw_input('Enter file name: ')  # user file name
if aFile == '':
    aFile = 'orginal.csv'  # default file name
myCSV = csv.DictReader(open(aPath + aFile, 'r'), delimiter=',')
print myCSV.fieldnames # verify fieldnames

with open("output.csv", "wb") as ofile:
    w = csv.writer(ofile)
    for p in myCSV:
        try:
            p = dict((k, v) for k, v in p.iteritems()
                if v.lower() != 'null')
        except AttributeError, e:
            print e
            print p
            raise Exception()
    # reformats the columns of data for the output.csv
        pID = p.get('Last Name')[-4:]
        pName = p.get('Last Name')[:-4].strip() + ', ' + p.get('First Name')
        pDate = p.get('Start Time')[:-5]
        pBlank = p.get('')
        pCourse = p.get('Assigned Through')
        pScore = p.get('Score')[:-1]

    # verifies the new columns
        print pID, pName, pDate, pBlank, pCourse, pBlank, pBlank, pScore

    # NOT working...Only writes the last row of the orginal.csv to output.csv
        w.writerow([pID, pName, pDate, pBlank, pCourse, pBlank, pBlank, pScore])
```

Things we changed:

1. We used the `with` operator. When working with opening and closing files, using `with` is a generally accepted protocol to follow unless otherwise inapplicable since it handles the closing of files properly, among other things.
2. Use `wb` instead of just `w` as your second argument to `open`. This will allow you to open the file in write-binary mode. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3348460/python-getting-rid-of-extra-line) for reference.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you again @Nanashi.  This community is the greatest!

Comment: You're welcome and good luck. As a final aside, check out the Pandas library when you have time. You might find it extremely useful for CSV manipulations like this. :)

Answer (score 3):

You are re-opening the file and overwriting it on each pass through the `for p in myCSV` loop.  You need to create `w` once before entering the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you're re-writing your output file at each iteration ...
You should simply take the line

```
w = csv.writer(open("output.csv", "w"))
```

out of the loop as :

```
w = csv.writer(open("output.csv", "w"))
try:
    for p in myCSV:
        try:
            ...
            w.writerow([pID, pName, pDate, pBlank, pCourse, pBlank, pBlank, pScore])
finally:
    w.close()
```

You could also have a look to "with" constructs that automatically cope with potential io errors and close the file at end of block with no need for the additional try.