# How to store data in CSV file?

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have some data I want to store in a csv file:

```
result  |  DataFrame  |  (90422, 17)  |  Column names: age, job, marital
```

However, my script only creates an empty csv file. How can I get it to actually output the data that I want?

```
for row in result:
    counter[row[0]] += 1
writer = csv.writer(open('file.csv', 'w'))
for row in result:
    if counter[row[0]] >= 0:
        writer.writerows(row)
```

Comment: please code data and code here in the question itself as text

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3348460/csv-file-written-with-python-has-blank-lines-between-each-row

Comment: DataFrame has a `to_csv` method so you can just use result.to_csv(filename) http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the `to_csv` method integrated in the `pandas` library

```
my_dataframe.to_csv('name_of_file', sep=',')
```