# Using Python to populate a csv file

Tags: python, csv

The following piece of code creates a CSV file, but every other line is blank. How can I prevent these linebreaks from happening?

```
import datetime
import time
import csv

i = 0
while i < 10:
    TempProbe = "78.12" 
    CurrentTime = time.strftime("%x")
    CurrentDate = time.strftime("%I:%M:%S")
    stringAll = TempProbe + "," + CurrentTime + "," + CurrentDate
    print(stringAll)
    file = open("outFile.csv", "a")
    csvWriter = csv.writer( file )
    csvWriter.writerow( [TempProbe, CurrentTime,CurrentDate] )
    file.close()
    i = i + 1
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Works perfect for me as it is on 2.7

Answer (score 5):

This is probably because the default line terminator is `'\r\n'`. You can correct this by passing `lineterminator='\n'` to your `csv.writer` object, like so:

```
csvWriter = csv.writer(file, lineterminator='\n')
```

P.S. Move this line out of your `while` loop to avoid destroying and recreating the file writer object.

Comment: I never understood while people are using `csv` library for saving files. Since `*.csv` files are simple text files, it's perfectly good (and faster) to just create a proper string and dump it into the file.

Comment: I find the `dictwriter` of the `csv` module very handy. Much neater than dumping into the file directly. It even gets better when you need to open a tab delimited file.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the lineterminator for your csvWriter, as in the code below.

```
csvWriter = csv.writer(file, lineterminator='\n')
```

For an explanation why, see: [CSV file written with Python has blank lines between each row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3348460/csv-file-written-with-python-has-blank-lines-between-each-row)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the `open` function to write a csv file:

```
file = open("outFile.csv", "a")
file.write(stringAll+'\n')
```

Also, you should take the file `open` and `close` functions out of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Use this: 'ab' vs 'a',writes binary should fix the problem

```
file = open("outFile.csv", "ab")
csvWriter = csv.writer(file, lineterminator='\n' )
```

or this you dont need to open/close on every write :

```
file      = open("outFile.csv", "ab")
csvWriter = csv.writer(file, lineterminator='\n' )

i = 0
while i < 10:
    TempProbe = "78.12" 
    CurrentTime = time.strftime("%x")
    CurrentDate = time.strftime("%I:%M:%S")
    stringAll = TempProbe + "," + CurrentTime + "," + CurrentDate
    print(stringAll)
    csvWriter.writerow( [TempProbe, CurrentTime,CurrentDate] )   
    i = i + 1
    time.sleep(1)

file.close()
```