# Python OrderedDict to CSV: Eliminating Blank Lines

Tags: python, csv, line-breaks, ordereddictionary

When I run this code...

```
from simple_salesforce import Salesforce
sf = Salesforce(username='un', password='pw', security_token='tk')
cons = sf.query_all("SELECT Id, Name FROM Contact WHERE IsDeleted=false LIMIT 2")

import csv

with open('c:\test.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    fieldnames = ['contact_name__c', 'recordtypeid']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)

    writer.writeheader()
    for con in cons['records']:    
        writer.writerow({'contact_name__c': con['Id'], 'recordtypeid': '082I8294817IWfiIWX'})

print('done')
```

I get the following output inside my CSV file...

```
contact_name__c,recordtypeid

xyzzyID1xyzzy,082I8294817IWfiIWX

abccbID2abccb,082I8294817IWfiIWX
```

I'm not sure why those extra lines are there.

**Any tips for getting rid of them so my CSV file will be normal-looking?**

I'm on Python 3.4.3 according to `sys.version_info`.

---

Here are a few more code-and-output pairs, to show the kind of data I'm working with:

```
from simple_salesforce import Salesforce
sf = Salesforce(username='un', password='pw', security_token='tk')
print(sf.query_all("SELECT Id, Name FROM Contact WHERE IsDeleted=false LIMIT 2"))
```

produces

```
OrderedDict([('totalSize', 2), ('done', True), ('records', [OrderedDict([('attributes', OrderedDict([('type', 'Contact'), ('url', '/services/data/v29.0/sobjects/Contact/xyzzyID1xyzzy')])), ('Id', 'xyzzyID1xyzzy'), ('Name', 'Person One')]), OrderedDict([('attributes', OrderedDict([('type', 'Contact'), ('url', '/services/data/v29.0/sobjects/Contact/abccbID2abccb')])), ('Id', 'abccbID2abccb'), ('Name', 'Person Two')])])])
```

and

```
from simple_salesforce import Salesforce
sf = Salesforce(username='un', password='pw', security_token='tk')
cons = sf.query_all("SELECT Id, Name FROM Contact WHERE IsDeleted=false LIMIT 2")
for con in cons['records']:
    print(con['Id'])
```

produces

```
xyzzyID1xyzzy
abccbID2abccb
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSV file written with Python has blank lines between each row](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3348460/csv-file-written-with-python-has-blank-lines-between-each-row)

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't found that one - probably because I kept putting "ordereddict" into my search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two likely possibilities: the output file needs to be opened in binary mode and/or the writer needs to be told not to use DOS style line endings.

To open the file in binary mode in Python 3 replace your current `with open` line with:

```
with open('c:\test.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
```

to eliminate the DOS style line endings try:

```
writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames, lineterminator="\n")
```

Comment: Thanks - it works with either of your suggestions, as well as with both of them together.  Observations:  When I open them in Helios Software Solutions's "Textpad," the 1-or-the-other output files have 2 spaces at the end of each line in the highlighting when I "ctrl+a," but no extra end-padding when I, say, cursor through the text or click beyond the end of the line.  The "both-and" output has just 1 space of "ctrl+a" highlighting overshoot in this software and, again, no "perceptible" spaces otherwise.  All 3 open the same to the naked eye in Excel and, I'm sure, will work for my purpose.

Comment: You're welcome. Yeah, a lot depends on your environment. Different platforms have different assumptions about line endings, and different editors treat different types of line endings in different ways. DOS-style line endings use two characters rather than the one used by Linux / UNIX / Mac / BSD / etc.