# Eliminating blank gap row after row

Tags: python, python-2.7

I would like to eliminate blank gap row after row! Please refer to the pic for better overview. What is wrong with the code? notepad format seems fine while when viewed from excel, space just occur for every entries including the first time after the header input

Comment: python 2.7 here

Comment: Even though your problem is solved make sure you look at the duplicate question read the accepted answer for *why* this was happening.  Also, if Leuthus's answer helped you, upvote his answer and mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the python version you are using:

```
# Python 2
with open('/pythonwork/thefile_subset11.csv', 'wb') as outfile:
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)

# Python 3
with open('/pythonwork/thefile_subset11.csv', 'w', newline='') as outfile:
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)
```

Credits to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3348664/5415084

So, in summary: python 3 requires an additional parameter `newline=''` while using the `w` parameter and python 2 requires the `wb` parameter while opening the file.

Comment: python 2.7 here

Comment: Did you try what's been described above? Is it working for you?

Comment: i merely added "b" in wb `with open("sample_data.csv") as f, open("out.csv", "w") as out:` however error returned 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\Function 6 - still in progress.py", line 7, in <module>
    next(reader)
StopIteration

Comment: Change 2 - `with open("sample_data.csv", "wb" ) as f, open("out.csv", "wb") as out:`
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Acer\Desktop\Function 6 - still in progress.py", line 7, in <module>
    next(reader)
IOError: File not open for reading

Comment: Is the previous run still running?

Comment: `"sample_data.csv"` needs to be opened `"rb"` not `"wb"`.

Comment: previous refering to the first change? @Steven Rumbalski Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\Function 6 - still in progress.py", line 7, in <module>
    next(reader)
StopIteration

Comment: use `rb` parameter on the file you will read from and use `wb` param on the file you will write to. Just like @StevenRumbalski said.

Comment: @KaelTee:  Your `"sample_data.csv"` is blank because on a previous run of your program it was opened for writing (`with open("sample_data.csv", "wb") as f`).  So when you call `next(reader)` there is no next row because there are no rows in the file.  Opening a file for writing overwrites the existing file.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski IT WORKS NOW! As you said, my sample_data.csv is blank. Thank ou!