# Python csv library leaves empty rows even when using a valid lineterminator

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to fetch data from the internet to save it to a csv file.
I am facing a problem with writing to the csv file, the library leaves an empty row in the file

[image: Example]

The data is random.org integers in text/plain format.

---

I'm using urllib.request to fetch the data and I am using this code to get the data and decode it

```
req = urllib.request.Request(url, data=None, headers={
    'User-Agent': '(some text)'})

with urllib.request.urlopen(req) as response:
    html = response.read()
    encoding = response.headers.get_content_charset('utf-8')
    data = html.decode(encoding)
```

I am using this line of code to open the csv file :`csvfile = open('data.csv', "a")`
Writing to the file:
`writer = csv.writer(csvfile, lineterminator = '\n')
 writer.writerows(data)`
and of course I close the file at the end

---

Things I tried and didn't help :

- Using (lineterminator = '\n') when writing
- Using (newline = "") when opening the file
- Defining a "delimiter" and a "quotechar" and "quoting"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSV file written with Python has blank lines between each row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3348460/csv-file-written-with-python-has-blank-lines-between-each-row)

Comment: @HFBrowning Mentioned that newline="'' didn't help

Comment: Okay, are you using Python 2.x? You may need to provide more code to explain if your problem is not covered by the post I linked to

Comment: I am using Python 3.6.1.
On the code side I don't have much to share, but I'll update my urllib request section

Comment: Could you please add the relevant part of your script/view to your question?

Comment: What is the value of `data`, exactly?

Comment: @PeterWood
"data" as printed by the console(example)
`
1
1
1
0
1
`
example from a page : [Random.org link](https://www.random.org/integers/?num=5&min=0&max=1&col=1&base=10&format=plain&rnd=new)

Comment: These white spaces aren't in the console.

Comment: Noticed some white spaces in the webpage, these are not getting written in the file and the method strip() didn't help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated Answer**

If when you create the list that is being written to the `data` list, if you add it as a list so that `data` becomes a list of lists, then set your line delimiter to be `'\n'`, it should work. Below is the working code I used to test.

```
import csv
import random

csvfile = open('csvTest.csv', 'a')
data = []
for x in range(5):
    data.append([str(random.randint(0, 100))])

writer = csv.writer(csvfile, lineterminator = '\n')
writer.writerows(data)
csvfile.close()
```

and it outputs

[image]

Comment: as an additional note, this was done with the default line terminator.

Comment: I was using binary mode, then I got into problems of converting str to byte(either an error or writing wrong data like 48 and 49), any help ?

Comment: you can set the dialect to `excel-tab` which will cause the numbers > 9 to be separated by a tab but they will appear correctly in Excel.

`writer = csv.writer(csvfile, dialect = 'excel-tab')`

Comment: Also, using binary mode didn't help unfortunately.

Comment: This works but it keeps using the same value that is getting fetched the first time like : (0,0,0,0,0), I want to figure it out by myself. Thank you <3