# Python - CSV module, skipping rows

Tags: python, csv

I'm trying to create a .csv file using python. The .csv file is successfully created however it skips a row between entries giving the result below.

```
['Name', 'Profession']
[]
['Derek', 'Software Developer']
[]
['Steve', 'Software Developer']
[]
['Paul', 'Manager']
[]
```

Any help in fixing this would be greatly appreciated.

```
import csv

with open('persons.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    filewriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',',
                            quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    filewriter.writerow(['Name', 'Profession'])
    filewriter.writerow(['Derek', 'Software Developer'])
    filewriter.writerow(['Steve', 'Software Developer'])
    filewriter.writerow(['Paul', 'Manager'])


with open('persons.csv', 'rt') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)

    # read file row by row
    for row in reader:
        print(row)
```

Comment: check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3348460/csv-file-written-with-python-has-blank-lines-between-each-row

Answer (score 0):

I was mistakenly using python 2 syntax rather than pythonn 3, I should have had `newline=''` as a parameter in `with open('persons.csv', 'w') as csvfile:` to give `with open('persons.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:`