# writing json data to csv file using python/pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I'm getting the data from mongodb & using csv.DictWriter method to write the json values to the csv file, but while writing I'm getting a blank line after each row.

How to avoid these blank lines?

Code Snippet: (I'm doing some data manipulation which i didn't include here)

```
with open('test_output.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
  fields = ['date', 'ns', 'storageSize']
  writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fields)
  writer.writeheader()
  stats = client['db_stats'].coll_stats.find({})
  for x in stats:
     writer.writerow({'date': x["date"], 'ns': x["ns"], 'storageSize': x["storageSize"]});
```

Output:(with blank lines after each write)

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSV file written with Python has blank lines between each row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3348460/csv-file-written-with-python-has-blank-lines-between-each-row)

Answer (score 0):

You can fix the problem after the fact with pandas:

```
import pandas as pd # import pandas
data = pd.read_csv('test_output.csv') # pull in csv file
data = data.iloc[::2] # chop every 2nd row from frame
data.to_csv('test_output.csv',index=False) # save over csv
```

You should be able to just add the snippet above to the end of your existing code.

Comment: Would not use this method for large amounts of data.