# Python 3- converting text to CSV. How to properly format it(has an empty line every other line)

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I am trying to convert the data [here](https://grid.cs.gsu.edu/zcai/course/4980-6980/Dataset/TrainData1.txt) which I put in a text file to convert into CSV file.

This is the code:

```
import csv

txt_file = r"TestData1.txt"
csv_file = r"TestData1.csv"

in_txt = csv.reader(open(txt_file, "rt"), delimiter = '\t')
out_csv = csv.writer(open(csv_file, 'wt'))

out_csv.writerows(in_txt)
```

It works but has a empty line every other line. How do I go fix that?

Answer (score 0):

This question has already been addressed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3348460/csv-file-written-with-python-has-blank-lines-between-each-row).

In Python 3.x, it turns out that you can specify how you want to process the new line by adding `newline=''` (for no newline character).

```
import csv

txt_file = r"TestData1.txt"
csv_file = r"TestData1.csv"

in_txt = csv.reader(open(txt_file, "rt"), delimiter = '\t')
out_csv = csv.writer(open(csv_file, 'wt', newline=''))


out_csv.writerows(in_txt)
```

Comment: thanks for the link, so it's a duplicate.