# output and input dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

Hi I want to save a dictionary to csv, then input it. However on both output and input, I met some issues.

For output I tried: (D_FINAL is the dictionary)

```
f = open("D_FINAL.csv", "w")
writer = csv.writer(f)
for k, v in D_FINAL.items():
    writer.writerow([k, v])
f.close
```

It works fine but when I want to open the csv, it says the file is locked from editting

For input I tried

```
import csv
dict = {}
r = open('D_FINAL3.csv', 'r')
for k, v in csv.reader(r):
    dict[k] = v

r.close()
```

but I got error

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-92-d3e2b3081317> in <module>()
      3 dict = {}
      4 r = open('D_FINAL2.csv', 'r')
----> 5 for k, v in csv.reader(r):
      6     dict[k] = v
      7     
ValueError: not enough values to unpack 
(expected 2, got 0)
```

What's the correct way to do these ?

Comment: You are not calling `f.close()`, without the parentheses `f.close` is a no-op.

Comment: can you not use with open()?

Comment: Even better than calling `close()` by hand, use a [with block](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3012565/962190) to open/close your file.

Comment: Did you try same operation on output and input...? Maybe the code is not relevant on "For input I tried".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

on windows (python 3), if you don't use `open("D_FINAL.csv", "w",newline="")`, the resulting csv file has extra blank lines (because of the extra carriage return char inserted making end of lines like `\r\r\n`).

Unfortunately, those double carriage return chars are read back not the same way: it generates a blank row after each valid data row. So unpacking fails because there aren't any elements in the row.

More on this nasty side-effect: [CSV file written with Python has blank lines between each row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3348460/csv-file-written-with-python-has-blank-lines-between-each-row)

So when reading, you get a blank line.

Just do (and upgrade your python skills a notch):

```
with open("D_FINAL.csv", "w", newline="")  as f:  # python 2: use: "wb"
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(D_FINAL.items())
```

(write in one go with `writerows`, use a `with` block so you don't miss the call to `close` and the file isn't locked anymore)

Note that `json` module is best suited to read & write dictionaries (if your need is serialization)

Aside: it's better to read back using a better technique too (it seems that the `newline` thingy isn't really necessary when reading):

```
with open("D_FINAL.csv", "r", newline="")  as f:  # python 2: use: "rb"
    writer = csv.reader(f)
    output = {k:v for k,v in writer}  # unpack+dictionary comprehension
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the code you have given, it seems like you are not actually closing the file by calling `f.close()`. Changing `f.close` to `f.close()` should help you get over this issue. 
But remember you can improve your code by implementing a with block. for example,

```
with open("D_FINAL.csv", "w",newline="") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for k, v in D_FINAL.items():
        writer.writerow([k, v])
```

Comment: `open("D_FINAL.csv", "w")` isn't the proper way of writing a csv file.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre i just modified the code from question, so its easy for them to understand. i took your advice and changed it now. :) cheers!

Answer (score 0):

May be you can use `pandas` for this purpose

```
import pandas as pd
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data=D_FINAL, orient='index').to_csv('D_FINAL.csv')
```

Hope this helps.