# Using xlrd module to read an xlsx file and write as a csv file

Tags: python, csv, xlrd

I am using `xlrd` to read an xslx file and write it in csv format. When I open the csv file after running the code, there is an empty row after each filled one. I would like the information in the csv file to be a bit more condensed without any empty rows.

Here is my code:

```
import xlrd
import csv

def csv_from_excel():
    workbook = xlrd.open_workbook('refugee_camp.xlsx')
    sheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)
    converted_csv = open('refugeecamp.csv', 'w')
    wr = csv.writer(converted_csv, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)

    for rownum in range(sheet.nrows):
        wr.writerow(sheet.row_values(rownum))

    converted_csv.close()
    try:
        open_file = open("refugeecamp.csv", 'r')
        print("Yesss")
    except: 
        print("could not open file!")

csv_from_excel()
```

The first 9 rows of data:

```
0   Coxs_Bazar  Ukhia   Palong Khali    Spontaneous Site    Camp 2E CXB-203 C2E_MQ_1    MQ  Mosque  21.21224574 92.16796803 priv_don    n/a No  No  No  No  G:\ROUND 4 Infrastructure\Round4_Infrastructure_Media\1517726967388.jpg    
1   Coxs_Bazar  Ukhia   Palong Khali    Spontaneous Site    Camp 2E CXB-203 C2E_CF_1    CF  Child Friendly Space    21.21258107 92.16746224 ngo_un  Unicef  No  Yes No  Yes G:\ROUND 4 Infrastructure\Round4_Infrastructure_Media\1517727585008.jpg
2   Coxs_Bazar  Ukhia   Palong Khali    Spontaneous Site    Camp 2E CXB-203 C2E_MD_1    MD  Madrassah   21.21039682 92.16750261 priv_don    n/a No  No  No  No  G:\ROUND 4 Infrastructure\Round4_Infrastructure_Media\1517734071276.jpg
3   Coxs_Bazar  Ukhia   Palong Khali    Spontaneous Site    Camp 2E CXB-203 C2E_MD_2    MD  Madrassah   21.20590394 92.15938967 local_gov   n/a No  No  No  No  G:\ROUND 4 Infrastructure\Round4_Infrastructure_Media\1517822966880.jpg
4   Coxs_Bazar  Ukhia   Palong Khali    Spontaneous Site    Camp 2E CXB-203 C2E_CF_2    CF  Child Friendly Space    21.2059306  92.16004456 ngo_un  Mukti Ukaid Unicef  No  No  No  No  G:\ROUND 4 Infrastructure\Round4_Infrastructure_Media\1517807448979.jpg
5   Coxs_Bazar  Ukhia   Palong Khali    Spontaneous Site    Camp 2E CXB-203 C2E_MQ_2    MQ  Mosque  21.20411076 92.16006021 local_gov   n/a No  No  No  No  G:\ROUND 4 Infrastructure\Round4_Infrastructure_Media\1517818069995.jpg
6   Coxs_Bazar  Ukhia   Palong Khali    Spontaneous Site    Camp 2E CXB-203 C2E_MQ_3    MQ  Mosque  21.207251   92.16507649 priv_don    n/a No  No  No  No  G:\ROUND 4 Infrastructure\Round4_Infrastructure_Media\1517809273947.jpg
7   Coxs_Bazar  Ukhia   Palong Khali    Spontaneous Site    Camp 2E CXB-203 C2E_MQ_4    MQ  Mosque  21.2062252  92.1641497  priv_don    n/a No  No  No  No  G:\ROUND 4 Infrastructure\Round4_Infrastructure_Media\1517807655768.jpg
8   Coxs_Bazar  Ukhia   Palong Khali    Spontaneous Site    Camp 2E CXB-203 C2E_MQ_5    MQ  Mosque  21.20711018 92.16626172 priv_don    n/a No  No  No  No  G:\ROUND 4 Infrastructure\Round4_Infrastructure_Media\1517812725009.jpg
```

[Here is a link to the xlxs datafile](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JFMI9Rbv-F-OTbALwMmM8oOzX6GrW1_O/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Hi. I just added a pic of the original data as well.

Comment: The actual data is over 1000 rows. But, I'll add the first 10 rows as text

Comment: Hello! I added a shareable link to the original datafile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to SO! The empty rows are caused not because of data. You need to add a parameter while opening the csv file object called `newline`. Rewrite your code like,

```
with open('refugeecamp.csv', 'w', newline='') as converted_csv:
    writer = csv.writer(converted_csv, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
```

Refer this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3348664/3488550) for more details.

Hope this helps! Cheers!

Comment: Do an upvote if the answer helped and mark it as accepted if it worked. Happy knowledge sharing!