# Unstructured text file read in Python to make it structured

Tags: python, python-3.x

[File](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1dcWN9GlfRqUKQQUWXSeYMpv51BfwOXqm) I have this attached text file which contains unstructured data with some information lines before. How can i structurize this data (extract information in structured manner). So in the end i have several columns (in this case 5) and have the corresponding information in that. Frame 50 contains 10 values, Frame 51 contains 10 vales and so on and also get the first 4 lines value in separate.
I tried and come up with the following code. But this is not the best list/array i get.
Thanks

```
frame =[]
frame1 =[]

flag = -1
counter = -1
counter_val = 0
f = open(filepath, "r")
for line in f:
    element = line.split(' ')
    if(len(element) == 4):
        if(element[1] == "Frame_Number") :
            # print(element[1])
            if(flag == 0):
                # print(len(frame1))
                frame.append(frame1)
            flag = 0
            counter = counter + 1
            counter_val = 0
            frame1 =[]
        continue
    if(flag == 0):   
        frame1.append(line)
        counter_val = counter_val + 1

print(frame[1])
```

Comment: I think it would better to include snippet from input file and corresponding data structure (like dict, array, class) you would like to have as an output.

Comment: @sardok lets say its csv where first column contains the values of Frame_Number# 50 with header and so on

Comment: Would it be six rather than five column as in: `Values,Samples_per_Frame, Chirp_Time_sec,Pulse_Repetition_Time_sec,Frame_Period_sec, Frame_Number`?

Comment: @DarrylG No for the moment i dont need the upper values just the values under the Frame_Number.. So the Number of column depends on the number of frames i will have

Comment: @AR.--so what's in the five columns i.e. 'So in the end i have several columns (in this case 5)'?  Frame_Number would be a column, so what are the other four?  The data is 10 elements so that would be either 10 (column for each value) or 1 (place all data in the same column).

Comment: @DarrylG i will have a matrix [5 x10] in this case , where Frame number 50, Frame 51 ... are my columns with 10 values each

Comment: @AR.--I posted an answer.  Does it conform to your requirements?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a pandas solution,

```
import pandas as pd

# Read in the data as a Pandas Series
df = pd.read_csv('testsd.txt', sep = '\n', header = None, squeeze = True) 

# Get the names of the eventual column names ('# Frame_Number 50', ...)
colNames = df.loc[df.str.startswith('# Frame_Number')]

# Store the first few lines of metadata in another frame and drop them from the original dataframe
meta_df = df[: colNames.index.to_list()[0]]]
df.drop(range(colNames.index.to_list()[0]), inplace = True)

# Drop the eventual column names
df.drop(colNames.index.to_list(), inplace = True)
```

What is left in the original dataframe should be just the data. Now reshape the dataframe. Note that this only works if every column has the same number of entries.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(df.values.reshape(len(colNames), int(len(df) / len(colNames))).T, columns = colNames)
```

The reshape function takes as arguments the desired number of rows and columns. It reshapes horizontally, so we will transpose the result. Finally if you want, add the metadata that we saved as a column of the dataframe, although you should really save it as a file someplace else.

```
df['meta'] = meta_df
```

Write the dataframe to file:

```
df.to_csv('testsd.csv')
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: OP, please note the edit where the transpose of the reshape function is used.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following

**Code**

```
import csv

def convert_csv(filenm):
  " Produces structured data by converting to CSV file "
  
  with open(filenm, 'r') as fin,  open('out.txt', 'w') as csvfile:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=' ',
                            quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    
    frames = []
    frame_vals = []
    for line in fin:
      line = line.rstrip()
      if line:
        if line[0] == "#":
          field, value = line[1:].split('=')
          field, value = field.strip(), value.strip()
          if field == 'Frame_Number':
            frames.append(value)    # current frame number
            frame_vals.append([])   # new sublist for frame values
        else:
          frame_vals[-1].append(line.strip())  # append to current frame values

    # Write header
    fnames = ['Frame_' + str(v) for v in frames]
    csv_writer.writerow(fnames)

    # write other data
    for row in zip(*frame_vals):  # transposing to get each frame in a column
      csv_writer.writerow(row)

convert_csv('testd.txt')
```

**Test**

*Input: testd.txt*

```
# Samples_per_Frame = 8192
# Chirp_Time_sec = 0.000133
# Pulse_Repetition_Time_sec = 0.00050355
# Frame_Period_sec = 0.2

# Frame_Number = 50
0.50061053
0.49938953
0.49426132
0.48962152
0.48791212
0.48937732
0.49523813
0.49914533
0.50158733
0.49914533
# Frame_Number = 51
0.50061053
0.49938953
0.49426132
0.48962152
0.48791212
0.48937732
0.49523813
0.49914533
0.50158733
0.49914533
# Frame_Number = 52
0.50793654
0.50647134
0.49841273
0.48937732
0.48644692
0.49035412
0.49768013
0.50647134
0.51282054
0.50940174
# Frame_Number = 53
0.49670333
0.49181932
0.4840049
0.48547012
0.48791212
0.49230772
0.49768013
0.49816853
0.49181932
0.48595852
# Frame_Number = 54
0.49352872
0.49597073
0.49987793
0.50354093
0.50402933
0.50036633
0.49841273
0.49743593
0.49865693
0.50012213
```

*Output: out.txt*

```
Frame_50 Frame_51 Frame_52 Frame_53 Frame_54
0.50061053 0.50061053 0.50793654 0.49670333 0.49352872
0.49938953 0.49938953 0.50647134 0.49181932 0.49597073
0.49426132 0.49426132 0.49841273 0.4840049 0.49987793
0.48962152 0.48962152 0.48937732 0.48547012 0.50354093
0.48791212 0.48791212 0.48644692 0.48791212 0.50402933
0.48937732 0.48937732 0.49035412 0.49230772 0.50036633
0.49523813 0.49523813 0.49768013 0.49768013 0.49841273
0.49914533 0.49914533 0.50647134 0.49816853 0.49743593
0.50158733 0.50158733 0.51282054 0.49181932 0.49865693
0.49914533 0.49914533 0.50940174 0.48595852 0.50012213
```

**Regex Version**

Changes

- Uses Regex to identified meta data
- Use dictionary to store field names and values
- field names are lines that begin with '#'
- field values are lines without '#'

*Code*

```
import re
import csv

def convert_csv(filenm):
  " Produces structured data by converting to CSV file "

  # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3348460/csv-file-written-with-python-has-blank-lines-between-each-row
  with open(filenm, 'r') as fin,  open('out.txt', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=' ',
                            quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    
    # Regex attern for # followed by non-digits followed by = followed by number (integer or float)
    meta_data_pattern = re.compile(r'# (\D+) = (\d+(?:\.\d+)?)')
    
    all_data = {}       # Will place unstructured data into this dictionary
                        # Lines with # will be key for dictionary
                        # Lines that follow without a '#' will be values for the dictionary key
    
    for line in fin:
        if (line := line.rstrip()):                        # remove end of line terminator
            if (m := meta_data_pattern.match(line)):       # check for match using assign expression (needs Python 3.8+)
                all_data.setdefault(f'{line}', [])         # start new append group with meta data
                
                # Update key used for current data
                last_key = next(reversed(all_data.keys())) # last key in dictionary
            else:
                all_data[last_key].append(line)             # append to current field
                
    # Remove fields with no data
    all_data = {k:v for k, v in all_data.items() if v}
    
    # Insure all fields the same length
    max_len = len(max(all_data.values(), key = len))
    
    for k, v in all_data.items():
        all_data[k] += ['NaN'] * (max_len - len(v))           # Pad all to same length
        
    # Get field names
    fnames = [f"{m.group(1).split('_')[0]}_{m.group(2)}" for field in all_data.keys() if (m:=meta_data_pattern.match(field))]
     
    # Dividing frame data into chunks by the number of frames by column
    frame_data = list(zip(*all_data.values()))

    csv_writer.writerow(fnames)  # Write header

    # write other data
    for row in frame_data:
        print(row)
        csv_writer.writerow(row)

convert_csv('test.txt')
```

Comment: thanks for the example. Any way to make it work with Regex instead ot the hardcoded `field == 'Frame_Number'` ? Unsuccessfully tested with (import re) `pattern = re.match(" [A-Z].*[A-Z] =", filenm) 
                    if field == pattern:` https://i.imgur.com/BrkDnks.png  And How about doing it with uneven columns lenghts too? (missing the tester3 line) https://i.imgur.com/jez6Q5P.png

Comment: @Lod added a regex version.  One issue with your regex pattern is that it only looks for uppercase letter i.e. [A-Z] while the data has Upper, lower, and underscore.  Use \D which checks for non-digits.

Comment: Thanks and sorry for the late reply I could do the testing just now. It does work for INPUT 1 but returns divide by zero error on INPUT 2. Also It doesn't return extra rows from uneven columns. Any fix for those two issues? Here's the inputs and prints: https://pastecode.io/s/priydjj5
and screenshots here:
INPUT 2: Divide By Zero error: https://i.imgur.com/NKtTIRh.png

INPUT 1 with Extra rows /Uneven Columns: https://i.imgur.com/eHgkSh6.png

INPUT 1 ORIGINAL: https://i.imgur.com/g1mid5g.png

Comment: @Lod check updated code.  It creates CSV uses space as delimiter, and quotes fields with spaces.  An alternative would be to use comma as delimiter, then quotes would not be needed.  This can be changed by modifying the line: `csv_writer = ...`

Comment: Thanks no more error now. I did 2 extra tests with uneven rows and got these 2 results:
INPUT 1: https://i.imgur.com/MWhFbjp.png  INPUT 2: https://i.imgur.com/WFLXpCx.png
Test data: https://pastecode.io/s/9jkqhip3
Any fix for the uneven rows problems?

Comment: @Lod try updated solution.  Fixed uneven rows by extending all rows to the same maximum length.  Used NaN for values when extending the row length.

Comment: Great! Many thanks. Sorry again for late reply, got able to test just now. Results as expected here: https://i.imgur.com/cOLAxmN.png Many thanks again. Be well!

Comment: @Lod are the results as desired?

Comment: Sorry again for late reply. Yes, for now and for my use it is very good script so far. I'll do more testing of similar dataset asa and be back with results if new issues arise. Till then, many thanks again. You be well!

Comment: Hi. I got a new error about charmap on a new dataset: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\mytest\printtest.py", line 163, in <module>
    convert_csv("testf.txt")
  File "C:\mytest\printtest.py", line 122, in convert_csv
    for line in fin:
  File "C:\Python39\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 5458: character maps to <undefined>
[Finished in 124ms]`

Comment: I made this little tweaking and seems to wokr now: `with open(filenm, "r", encoding="utf8")` (from this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9233027/unicodedecodeerror-charmap-codec-cant-decode-byte-x-in-position-y-character )

Comment: @Lod  that seems like a great solution.