# How can I replace first line of a csv with a header using Python?

Tags: python, csv

I'm trying to replace the first line of a csv input file with a header.  The first line is blank, 0. See image below.

[image]

I want the blank and 0 to be "ID" and "sil_score" respectively.  See below:

[image]

But I keep getting this:

[image]

```
import csv
r = csv.reader(open('C:/Users/Desktop/Geosill/attempt1.csv')) 
lines = list(r)

lines[1][0] = 'ID'
lines[2][0] = 'sil_score'


writer = csv.writer(open('C:/Users/Desktop/Geosill/attempt3.csv', 'w'))
writer.writerows(lines)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do it.  `newline=''` should be used to fix the [blank line](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3348664/235698) issue you are seeing as well.

```
import csv

with open('input.csv',newline='') as f:
    r = csv.reader(f)
    lines = list(r)

lines[0] = ['ID','sil_score']

with open('output.csv','w',newline='') as f:
    w = csv.writer(f)
    w.writerows(lines)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to edit the first two lines of the .csv you'll have to change how you access the *lines* list.

You'll need to use

```
lines[0][0]='ID'
lines[0][1]='sil_score'
```

instead.

The output seems odd though, could be something weird with the csv import. Try opening the files in a text editor, might be easier to see what's going on.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this without using csv.writer. Try this:

```
with open('C:/Users/Desktop/Geosill/attempt1.csv', "r") as infile:
    lines = infile.readlines().rstrip().split(",")
lines[0] = ["ID", "sil_score"]
with open('C:/Users/Desktop/Geosill/attempt1.csv', "w") as outfile:
    for line in lines:
        outfile.write(",".join(line))
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: No, you need writer to write a lists to a csv.  Check your results.  `lines` is a list of lists.

Comment: Yes, and I am joining the list elements with a comma. I don't believe we NEED CSV writer. I just use the regular file writer.

Comment: Until you have commas and quotes in the content and then it breaks.

Comment: Yes, agreed. But since @bkGeog only wants to change the headers to text, I think it will be fine.

Comment: For this user, not the next one.