# Python problems writing rows in CSV

Tags: python-3.x

I have this script that reads a CSV and saves the second column to a list, I'm trying to get it to write the contents of the list to a new CSV. The problem is every entry should have its own row but the new file sets everything into the same row.

I've tried moving the second `with open` code to within the first `with open` and I've tried adding a for loop to the second `with open` but no matter what I try I don't get the right results.

Here is the code:

```
import csv
col_store=[]      
with open('test-data.csv', 'r') as rf:
    reader = csv.reader(rf)
    for row in reader:
        col_store.append(row[1])
with open('meow.csv', 'wt') as f:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(f)
    csv_writer.writerows([col_store])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using 'writerows' treating 'col_store' as a list with one item.

The simplest approach to fixing this is calling

```
csv_writer.writerows(col_store)
# instead of 
csv_writer.writerows([col_store])
```

However, this will lead to a probably unwanted result - having blank lines between the lines.

To solve this, use:

```
with open('meow.csv', 'wt', newline='') as f:
     csv_writer = csv.writer(f)
     csv_writer.writerows(col_store)
```

For more about this, see [CSV file written with Python has blank lines between each row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3348460/csv-file-written-with-python-has-blank-lines-between-each-row)

Note: writerows expects *'an iterable of **row objects**'* and *'row objects must be an interable of strings or numbers'*.
(https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html)
Therefore, in the generic case (trying to write integers for examlpe), you should use Sam's solution.

Comment: Thanks, that works but now each row has all these commas. this column held skus so it each row should have something like ba0011 instead its  showing b,a,0,0,1,1

Comment: Which commas exactly? could you give the exact example?

Comment: Shouldn't this lead to an error? `_csv.Error: iterable expected, not int (something similar)`

Comment: Looking at the example I don't think it should. Note that col_store is initiated to be a list and items are added using .append method, which makes it an iterable.

Comment: I think it works not because of that reason, it works because every element in that list is a string. So strings are iterable. so its an iterable of iterables.. but yes it works.

Answer (score 2):

In your case if you have a column of single letters/numbers then Y.R answer will work.

To have a code that works in all cases, use this.

```
with open('meow.csv', 'wt') as f:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(f)
    csv_writer.writerows(([_] for _ in col_store))
```

From [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) it is mentioned that `writerows` expect an an iterable of row objects. Every row object should be an iterable of strings or numbers for Writer objects

Comment: thanks this worked but even after looking at the doc you linked to I dont quite understand why.

Comment: A row in a csv is a list of elements.. So when you want to `writerows`, you should pass a list of list-of-elements. btw, i am using the term list to easily understand, in reality all it expects is a iterable type.