# My CSV file is displaying the data correctly, but there are empty lines between each row

Tags: python, python-3.x

I made a CSV file that contains a book, its author, and the year it released. My problem is that when the data is displayed in the file its displayed every other line.
[image]

How can I make it where there aren't gaps between the data entries

my code:

```
import csv

amount = int(input("How many records would you like to add: "))
count = 0

with open("Books.csv", "w", newline="") as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    writer.writerow(["", "Book", "Author", "Year released"])

while count < amount:

    book = input("Enter a book: ")
    author = input("Enter it's Author: ")
    year = input("Enter the year it released: ")

    headers = [count, book, author, year]
    with open("Books.csv", 'a') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerow(headers)

    count += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You always need to supply `newline=""` on opening the file.
You do so when opening to write the header, but not for the data:

> ```
> with open("Books.csv", 'a') as f:    # missing newline = ''
> ```

From [csv.writer](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.writer)

> csv.**writer**(*csvfile*, dialect='excel', **fmtparams)
> Return a writer object responsible for converting the user’s data into
> delimited strings on the given file-like object. csvfile can be any
> object with a write() method. If csvfile is a *file object*, it should
> be opened with `newline=''`

- I wouldn't open the file all the time, just keep it opened.
- I also would opt for a for-loop to remove the need of increasing `count` yourself
- lastly when converting user input to integrs, use a try-except to avoid crashing your program on bad inputs

Code:

```
import csv

# someone could input -42 here - or garbage
while True:
    try:
        amount = int(input("How many records would you like to add: "))
        if amount >= 0:
            break
    except ValueError:
        pass  

with open("Books.csv", "w", newline="") as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    writer.writerow(["", "Book", "Author", "Year released"])

    for nr in range(count):
    
        book = input("Enter a book: ")
        author = input("Enter it's Author: ")
        year = input("Enter the year it released: ")
    
        data = [nr + 1, book, author, year]
        writer.writerow(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of `with open("Books.csv", 'a') as f:` use `with open("Books.csv", 'a', newline='') as f:`

Please refer [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3348664/6701627) for more deetails.