# How to correctly write (H:M) time format into a newline without commas after each number into an existing CSV using python?

Tags: python, csv

I have an existing csv file *"meetingschedule.csv"* and into its new column in *'Time'* row , I have to add the current time in **(%H:%M) format** after the *4 columns of given times*. But with my code , I am always getting the Time with commas in between:(

Like the Time --> *18:39* would be written as *"1,8,:,3,9"* as in the following *meetingschedule.csv* file -

```
Time,Meeting ID,Passcode
06:47, 999 9722 2425,
16:59, 999 9722 2425,
20:02, 999 9722 2425,
18:08, 999 9722 2425,
1,8,:,3,9
```

What should I do to fix this issue!?  Also, If possible, also provide me the way to **insert a comma** and **copy the Meeting ID from the above row and paste it as per its above lines, followed by a comma** *(As the Meeting ID also is variable here)* after writing the Current_Time .

My Code is Given below--

```
import datetime , csv
from datetime import datetime

timestr = datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M")
with open("meetingschedule.csv","a") as csvFile:
    Fileout = csv.writer(csvFile)
    Fileout.writerow(timestr)
```

For example, I require the output as --

```
Time,Meeting ID,Passcode
06:47, 999 9722 2425,
16:59, 999 9722 2425,
20:02, 999 9722 2425,
18:08, 999 9722 2425,
18:39, 999 9722 2425,
```

Thanks For the Help !

Comment: `Fileout.writerow([timestr, '', ''])`

Comment: Thanks but its leaving an empty line before the timestr... Also, The Meeting ID also should be written to the csv....Thanksss bro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`csvwriter.writerow()` takes a *iterable* (usually a `list`) with items to place in each column.  Passing a string (an iterable of characters) ends up placing a single character in each column.  To write the columns as described, you need a list of three items.  To have a trailing comma, the last item should be an empty string.

Also make sure to open the file with `newline=''` as stated in the `csv` documentation.  See [csv-file-written-with-python-has-blank-lines-between-each-row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3348460/csv-file-written-with-python-has-blank-lines-between-each-row/3348664#3348664) for why.

```
import datetime , csv
from datetime import datetime

timestr = datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M")
with open("meetingschedule.csv","a",newline='') as csvFile:
    Fileout = csv.writer(csvFile)
    Fileout.writerow([timestr,'999 9722 2425',''])
```

Given your input file, and that you want to copy the previous line meeting value, you can read all the lines in, append a new one with the appropriate data, and write it back out:

```py
import csv
from datetime import datetime

with open('meetingschedule.csv',newline='') as f:
    lines = list(csv.reader(f))
    
timestr = datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M")
addline = [timestr,lines[-1][1],''] # new information and previous ID
lines.append(addline)

with open('meetingschedule.csv','w',newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(lines)  # NOTE plural writerows takes a list of lists.
```

Comment: Thank U Soo much broo...U did really understand my question ! ..I did not really expect to have such a clarified solution...Thanks again..

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question, you want to make a .csv file with multiple rows and add the timestamp in the first column? Probably the easiest way for you to do this is create a csv writer and specify the delimiter and just add the data with your lists. I named it new_writer below...

```
import csv
from datetime import datetime

timestr = datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M")

with open("meetingschedule.csv", "a") as csvFile:
    new_writer = csv.writer(csvFile, delimiter=',')
    new_writer.writerow(['Time', 'Meeting ID', 'Passcode'])

    # Data
    new_writer.writerow(['timestr', 'meeting IDs', 'passcodes'])
```

Edit: I'm not sure I understood the question actually. Mark Tolonen seems to have understood the problem: you need to separate the data using a list (which you can see formatted in my .writerows)

Comment: Thanks and It seems you're right, @Mark Tolonen has actually got it right , but your solution is helpful too if I have to create a new csv with given conditions, but since I have to work on an existing csv file...hence I would like to follow his answer.. :)