# How to write to different columns using Python to CSV

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, csv

I am trying to write some values onto a CSV file but all the values are getting jammed into one column how do I use a different column for each value? Please go easy on me I am an absolute beginner with programming. It would be really helpful if someone could write an example code on how to solve this issue

Here is my code:

```
with open('log.csv', 'a',) as file:
    fieldnames = ['Timestamp', 'Overall result', 'Soll-orderno', 'Desired-HW-Version', 'Desired-SF-Version',
     'Desired-productcode', 'Desired-device-type', 'Scancode', 'Wbm-orderno', 'Wbm-HW-Version', 'Wbm-SF-Version',
      'Wbm-mac-address', 'test-product-code', 'combined-product-code' , 'wbm-device-type', 'test-device-type']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(file, fieldnames=fieldnames)

    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerow({'Timestamp':now, 'Overall result':'Blank', 'Soll-orderno':d_ordernum, 'Desired-HW-Version':d_hw_version, 'Desired-SF-Version':d_sf_version,
     'Desired-productcode':pc_praefix, 'Desired-device-type':d_dev_typ, 'Scancode':scancode_string, 'Wbm-orderno':ord_nmr, 'Wbm-HW-Version':v, 'Wbm-SF-Version':b,
      'Wbm-mac-address':mac_addr, 'test-product-code':'Blank', 'combined-product-code':product_code, 'wbm-device-type':dev_typ, 'test-device-type':'Blank'})
```

when I open the csv file using Excel it SHOULD look like this:
[image: What the excel sheet is supposed to look like]

But unfortunately my CSV file looks like this when i open it with Excel
[image: What the excel sheet looks like now]

As you can see all the values have gotten jam packed into one column instead of 1value:1column I would really appreciate it if you guys could show me how to do this. I think i am doing everything correctly but it still gets written only to one column. Please show me a solution for this problem if you guys can.

Comment: When you open it in Excel you need to tell Excel to use commas as the column separators. For whatever reason, it assumes you're going to want to use tabs.

Comment: @Kemp tab is the default delimiter for .txt files, comma is the default delimiter for .csv files (hence the name, csv = comma separated values).

Comment: @NicholasHunter I know that, but historically I've had issues with Excel assuming tabs when opening a csv file and that seemed to match what was happening in the question. I've checked just now with Excel 365 and it doesn't seem to happen though.

Comment: A separate issue that I can see happening in that screenshot is the extra blank lines you get when using the csv module on Windows. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3348460/csv-file-written-with-python-has-blank-lines-between-each-row) for the solution.

Comment: You’re appending to the output file; what’s already in the file may be making excel think the separator is tab. And you should open the file with `newline=‘’` as shown in _all_ the examples in the `csv` documentation https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html?highlight=csv#module-csv