# Python Formatting comma separated text string to save as csv file

Tags: python, csv

I have comma separated text (string format) from as output from an API call, an small example shown below.

`cs_file  = 'Reviewer Name,Account Reviewer Name,Account Manager Name\r\n"Last, First","Last, First","Last, First"'`

A new line is shown by '\r\n'. My thought would be to split the text at this first an then create a data frame by splitting at ",". However, splitting at '\r\n' does not work, just get one list...

`cs_list = []`

`cs_list = cs_file.split(r'\r\n')`

Any suggestions on a better approach? The goal would be to have this text saved as a csv.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The goal would be to have this text saved as a csv

The string is already in Excel CSV-file format, including proper quoting around fields that contain a delimiter and the newline format (\r\n).  Write the string directly to a file specifying the newlines to be written without translation:

```py
cs_file  = 'Reviewer Name,Account Reviewer Name,Account Manager Name\r\n"Last, First","Last, First","Last, First"'
with open('output.csv','w',newline='') as f:
    f.write(cs_file)
```

output.csv

```
Reviewer Name,Account Reviewer Name,Account Manager Name
"Last, First","Last, First","Last, First"
```

Note that `newline=''` is required in this case otherwise writing text on Windows translates `\n` to `\r\n`, resulting in `\r\r\n` when writing `\r\n` and then the CSV would display incorrectly if opened in Excel.  See [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3348460/csv-file-written-with-python-has-blank-lines-between-each-row/3348664#3348664) for more explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `cs_list = cs_file.split('\r\n')`.

Using a raw-string would have worked if you assigned `cs_file` with `cs_file  = 'Reviewer Name,Account Reviewer Name,Account Manager Name\\r\\n"Last, First","Last, First","Last, First"'`.

Python by default doesn't use raw-strings for assignment. I like to print strings to see how they visually look as all the escape characters can get confusing.