# AttributeError: '_csv.writer' object attribute 'writerow' is read-only

Tags: python, data-science

```
number =[1,2,3]
day = 4
year = 2022
with open('notables.csv', 'w') as notables:
    file_write=csv.writer(notables, delimiter = ',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)

    file_write.writerow=([number, day, year])
```

my error when running the above code is:
AttributeError: '_csv.writer' object attribute 'writerow' is read-only

I though csv.writer was used for writing? Am I not suppose to use .writerow here? What am I suppose to use?

Comment: file_write.writerow([number, day, year])

Comment: `file_write.writerow=([number, day, year])` Why are you _assigning_ to writerow?  Why is that equal sign there?

Comment: Voting to close as a typo.  Drop that `=` in `file_write.writerow=`.

Comment: FYI add `newline=''` parameter to `open` per `csv` module documentation.  See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3348460/csv-file-written-with-python-has-blank-lines-between-each-row).  And you can use `csv.writer(notables)` since the other parameters are the normal defaults.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the equals sign when you are writing the row, like this:

```
number =[1,2,3]
day = 4
year = 2022
with open('notables.csv', 'w') as notables:
    file_write=csv.writer(notables, delimiter = ',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    file_write.writerow([number, day, year])
```

Additionally, if you want to write multidimensional data, you will need to use `file_write.writerows({rows})`.
And, if the file doesn't exist yet, you will want to change the 'w' on line 4 to 'w+', to indicate that you want to create a new file.

Comment: You don't need `w+` for a new file.  `w` is fine.  `{rows}` is not correct, either.  that is set notation.

Comment: I was using the {} to enclose "rows" to indicate that that should be a variable. Sorry for the lack of clarification.