# how to add a Date column to existing csv file in python

Tags: python, json, csv

I have a Json file that I am converting and appending to a csv, and I am trying to also add a date column in the month/day/year format.

latest attempt:

```
import json
from csv import DictWriter
import pandas as pd
import datetime
with open('output.json', 'r') as inp, open('output.csv', 'a') as outp:
    writer = DictWriter(outp, fieldnames=[
        'name', 'price'])
    for line in inp:
        row = json.loads(line)
        writer.writerow(row)

a = pd.read_csv('output.csv')
a['Date'] = [datetime.date.today()]*len(a)
a.to_csv('adate.csv')
```

I get close to what I am trying to do.
output:

```
Lattice Top 6'W x 6'H King Cedar Aluminum/Composite Horizontal Fence-Starter Section-SURFACE MOUNT,"4,300 .",Date
"FENCESMART4U XCEL - Black Steel Anti-Rust Fence Gate - Sharp End Pickets - 4ft W x 5ft H - Easy Installation Kit, for Residential, Outdoor, Yard, Patio, Entry Way, 3-Rail Metal Gate",199 .,2022-10-18
"XCEL - Black Steel Anti-Rust Fence Gate - 4ft W x 5ft H - Easy Installation Kit, for Residential, Outdoor, Yard, Patio, Entry Way, 3-Rail Metal Gate",206 .,2022-10-18
"LZMZMQ Courtyard Baluster Garden Fencing Villa Outdoor Guardrail, Wide 100 120 140 160 180 cm Aluminum Fence Panels Deckorators, Grey Panels Decor Free Standing for Weatherproof","1,771 .",2022-10-18
```

the date gets inserted on the first row. I have tried adding column headers such as
`headerList = ['name', 'price', 'date']`
and that didn't go over well under the first column it removed the product names.

this is how the json file is reading in:

```
{"name": "Lattice Top 6'W x 6'H King Cedar Aluminum/Composite Horizontal Fence-Starter Section-SURFACE MOUNT", "price": "4,300 ."}
{"name": "FENCESMART4U XCEL - Black Steel Anti-Rust Fence Gate - Sharp End Pickets - 4ft W x 5ft H - Easy Installation Kit, for Residential, Outdoor, Yard, Patio, Entry Way, 3-Rail Metal Gate", "price": "199 ."}
{"name": "XCEL - Black Steel Anti-Rust Fence Gate - 4ft W x 5ft H - Easy Installation Kit, for Residential, Outdoor, Yard, Patio, Entry Way, 3-Rail Metal Gate", "price": "206 ."}
{"name": "LZMZMQ Courtyard Baluster Garden Fencing Villa Outdoor Guardrail, Wide 100 120 140 160 180 cm Aluminum Fence Panels Deckorators, Grey Panels Decor Free Standing for Weatherproof", "price": "1,771 ."}
```

Comment: Save yourself from tears and self-loathing, and choose a less crazy date format.

Comment: @tripleee the date format is `Y-m-d`, what's wrong with that?

Comment: That's perfect, but they say they want hamsters/anxiety/awake format.

Comment: @tripleee no idea how I missed that (or how you came up with name for it! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this all in `pandas` directly:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_json('output.json', orient='records', lines=True)
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime('today').strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
df.to_csv('adate.csv', index=False)
```

Output (for your sample data):

```
name,price,Date
Lattice Top 6'W x 6'H King Cedar Aluminum/Composite Horizontal Fence-Starter Section-SURFACE MOUNT,"4,300 .",10/22/2022
"FENCESMART4U XCEL - Black Steel Anti-Rust Fence Gate - Sharp End Pickets - 4ft W x 5ft H - Easy Installation Kit, for Residential, Outdoor, Yard, Patio, Entry Way, 3-Rail Metal Gate",199 .,10/22/2022
"XCEL - Black Steel Anti-Rust Fence Gate - 4ft W x 5ft H - Easy Installation Kit, for Residential, Outdoor, Yard, Patio, Entry Way, 3-Rail Metal Gate",206 .,10/22/2022
"LZMZMQ Courtyard Baluster Garden Fencing Villa Outdoor Guardrail, Wide 100 120 140 160 180 cm Aluminum Fence Panels Deckorators, Grey Panels Decor Free Standing for Weatherproof","1,771 .",10/22/2022
```

Comment: @Red sorry I somehow missed your desired date format from the question. I've updated the answer to suit. Please let me know if you need any other changes...

Answer (score 1):

You can do this directly without `pandas` if desired.  Make sure to use `newline=''` on files used with the `csv` module. ([why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3348460/csv-file-written-with-python-has-blank-lines-between-each-row/3348664#3348664))

```py
import json
from csv import DictWriter
from datetime import datetime

with open('output.json', 'r', newline='') as inp, open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as outp:
    writer = DictWriter(outp, fieldnames=['name', 'price', 'date'])
    writer.writeheader()
    for line in inp:
        row = json.loads(line)
        row['date'] = datetime.now().strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Output:

```
name,price,date
Lattice Top 6'W x 6'H King Cedar Aluminum/Composite Horizontal Fence-Starter Section-SURFACE MOUNT,4300.00,10/21/2022
"FENCESMART4U XCEL - Black Steel Anti-Rust Fence Gate - Sharp End Pickets - 4ft W x 5ft H - Easy Installation Kit, for Residential, Outdoor, Yard, Patio, Entry Way, 3-Rail Metal Gate",199.00,10/21/2022
"XCEL - Black Steel Anti-Rust Fence Gate - 4ft W x 5ft H - Easy Installation Kit, for Residential, Outdoor, Yard, Patio, Entry Way, 3-Rail Metal Gate",206.00,10/21/2022
"LZMZMQ Courtyard Baluster Garden Fencing Villa Outdoor Guardrail, Wide 100 120 140 160 180 cm Aluminum Fence Panels Deckorators, Grey Panels Decor Free Standing for Weatherproof",1771.00,10/21/2022
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution will make use of the parameter `restval`, which means if a value is missing, the `DictWriter` can use this value to fill in.

```py
import csv
import json
import datetime

today = datetime.date.today()
formatted_date = today.strftime("%Y/%m/%d")

with open("output.json") as instream, open("output.csv", "w") as outstream:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(
        outstream,
        fieldnames=["name", "price", "date"],
        restval=formatted_date
    )

    writer.writeheader()
    for line in instream:
        row = json.loads(line)
        writer.writerow(row)
```

So what I have here is almost the same as the original poster's code, but with `restval`.