# Still getting an error after using encode() when trying to write into a csv file

Tags: python, csv, web-scraping, encode, file-writing

Here's an example of the code:

```
import csv 
file = open("countries_information.csv", 'wb')
writer = csv.writer(file)
writer.writerow(['Country Name'.encode("utf-8)])
```

I get the error

```
"TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'"
```

I've browsed online for a solution, but I'm at a loss.

Comment: Don't manually encode.  Use the `encoding` parameter of `open` and use text mode `'w'`.

Answer (score 0):

Why aren't you specifying the format while opening the file? like:

```
import csv
file = open("countries_information.csv", 'w', encoding='utf-8')
writer = csv.writer(file)
writer.writerow(['Country Name'])
```

Comment: Per [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#module-contents), use `newline=''` when opening a file for csv.reader/csv.writer as well.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3348664/235698) for why.

Answer (score 0):

It's not obvious from the documentation, but `writerow` doesn't work with binary files. The official documentation doesn't mention this as far as I know, but the built-in help says

```
Help on built-in function writerow:

writerow(...) method of _csv.writer instance
    writerow(iterable)
    
    Construct and write a CSV record from an iterable of fields.  Non-string
    elements will be converted to string.
```

Your binary data is converted to a string `"b'Country Name'"` and the fail happens when the string is written to the underlying binary file object. This happens in a C extension so the stack trace misses those critical calls.

On the positive side, you can do things like `writerow([1,2,3])`, but you've now seen the negative side.