# Python Script Can not find file object to close

Tags: python-2.7

When running this simple script, the "output_file.csv" remains open. I am unsure about how to close the file in this scenario.

I have looked at other examples where the open() function is assigned to a variable such as 'f', and the object closed using f.close(). Because of the `with` / as `csv-file`, I am unclear as to where the file object actually is. Would anyone mind conceptually explaining where the disconnect is here? Ideally, would like to know:

1. how to check namespace for all open file objects
2. how to determine the proper method for closing these objects

## simple script to read columns of data where mapping in column 1 is blank, fill down

```
import csv

output_file = csv.writer(open('output_file.csv', 'w'))
csv.register_dialect('mydialect', doublequote=False, quotechar="'")

def csv_writer(data):
    with open('output_file.csv',"ab") as csv_file:
        writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter=',', lineterminator='\r\n', dialect='mydialect')
        writer.writerow(data)

D = [[]]
for line in open('inventory_skus.csv'):
    clean_line = line.strip()
    data_points = clean_line.split(',')
    print data_points
    D.append([line.strip().split(',')[0], line.strip().split(',')[1]])

D2 = D
for i in range(1, len(D)):
    nr = D[i]
    if D[i][0] == '':
        D2[i][0] = D[i-1][0]
    else:
        D2[i] = D[i]

for line in range(1, len(D2)):
    csv_writer(D2[line])
    print D2[line]
```

Comment: You're doing an unnecessary explicit `open` at the top of the script, and you don't close it. So why are you surprised that the file remains opened?

Comment: possible duplicate of [python csv - not closing file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3347775/python-csv-not-closing-file)

Comment: I initially tried putting output_file.close() at the end but am getting this error:
    output_file.close()
AttributeError: '_csv.writer' object has no attribute 'close'

removing the initial output_file = csv.writer(open('output_file.csv', 'w')) still caused the file to remain open

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you are creating two file objects (in two different ways). First one:

```
output_file = csv.writer(open('output_file.csv', 'w'))
```

This is hidden within a `csv.writer` and not exposed by the same, however 
you don't use that output writer at all, including not closing it. So it remains open until garbage collected.

In

```
 with open('output_file.csv',"ab") as csv_file:
```

you get the file object in `csv_file`. The context block takes care of closing the object, so no need to close it manually (file objects are context managers).

Manually indexing over `D2` is unnecessary. Also, why are you opening the CSV file in binary mode?

```
def write_data_row(csv_writer, data):
    writer.writerow(data)

with open('output_file.csv',"w") as csv_file:
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter=',', lineterminator='\r\n',   dialect='mydialect')

    for line in D2[1:]:
        write_data_row(writer, line)
        print line
```

Comment: Ah, thank you. I am removing the unnecessary output_file at the beginning. However, the second object seems to not be closed by the context block.

When I run in console, 'csv_file' is not defined outside of this block so am unsure how to close it.

Comment: How do you determine that it is not closed? If I try `writer.writerow('abc')` after the with-block I get `ValueError: I/O operation on closed file`.

Comment: when opening the output_file.csv i get an error from excel saying in use by another user/program

Comment: File objects have a `closed` property. Check that after the `with` block. Have you made sure that you do not have other references to the same file (like the one you just removed)?