# How to store data from a list in a .csv file?

Tags: python, csv

A list b is like:

```
X = [((a,b),12),((c,d),34),...]
for i in range(0,5):
    print X[i][0][0],X[i][1],X[i][0][1]
```

I want to save my data in a `csv` file. Eg. This can be saved as :

- `a,12,b`- in first row (which is `X[0][0][0], X[0][1]`)
- `c,34,d` - in my second row and so on.

This is part of my project and I have no idea about `.csv` file.

## What I did

```
writer= csv.writer(open('dict.csv','wb'))
for i in range(0,5):
    writer.writerow([x[i][0][0],x[i][1],x[i][0][1]])
```

But couldn't find anything in the csv file. How to fix it?

Comment: I edited your question  - `"a", 12` is not `X[0][0], X[1]` as you thought.

Comment: You do not close the file with `writer.close()`. The [`with` method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3347775/csv-writer-not-closing-file) is actually a better way of dealing with this.

Comment: Thanks @Tim , I corrected now.

Comment: @Nander, I am getting an error- '_csv.writer' object has no attribute 'close'.

Comment: @SOUBHIKRAKSHIT, sorry, not `writer.close()` but <file>.close(). See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not close the file:

```
f = open('dict.csv','wb')
writer= csv.writer(f)
for i in range(0,5):
    writer.writerow([x[i][0][0],x[i][1])
f.close() # close the file
```

Or better use the [answer with the `with` statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3347775/csv-writer-not-closing-file):

```
with open('dict.csv','wb') as outfile:
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)
    for i in range(0,5):
        writer.writerow([x[i][0][0],x[i][1])
```

Answer (score 1):

You were almost there.
while you write to csv , will default delimiter.
So just provide the data that should be written to csv.

```
import csv
x= [(('a','b'),12),(('c','d'),34)]
writer= csv.writer(open('dict.csv','wb'))

for i in range(0,2):
    writer.writerow([x[i][0][0]]+[x[i][1]])
```

Check this for more info. https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html